# Call a factory from Constructor to get a new version of "this"

Tags: c#, constructor

I may be going about this backwards...
I have a class which is like a document and another class which is like a template. They both inherit from the same base class and I have a method to create a new document from a template (or from another document, the method it is in the base class). 
So, if I want to create a new document from a template, I just instantiate the template and call GetNewDoc() on it;

```
Document doc = mytemplate.GetNewDoc();
```

In the Document class I have a blank constructor creating a new, blank document as well as another constructor that takes a document ID so I can load the document from the database. However, I would also like a constructor that takes a Template ID. This way I can do

```
Document doc = New Document(TemplateID)
```

Because the template class already has the ability to return a document, I'd like the constructor to do something like

```
Template temp = new Template(TemplateID);
this = temp.GetNewDoc();
```

Of course, I can't do this as "this" is read-only - and it feels odd anyway. I have a feeling I am being very stupid here so feel free to shout :)

The thing is that the object in question is pretty complex with several collections of child objects and database persistence over multiple tables so i don't want to duplicate too much code. Though, I guess I could just get the new document from the template and then copy the fields/properties across as the collections should follow easily enough - it just seems like duplication.

A more elaborate code example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Test
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // This just creates the object and assigns a value
        Instance inst = new Instance();
        inst.name = "Manually created";
        Console.WriteLine("Direct: {0}", inst.name);

        //This creates a new instance directly from a template
        MyTemplate def = new MyTemplate();
        Instance inst2 = def.GetInstance(100);
        Console.WriteLine("Direct from template: {0}", inst2.name);

        Instance inst3 = new Instance(101);
        Console.WriteLine("Constructor called the template: {0}", inst3.name);
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}

public class Instance
{
    public string name;

    public Instance(int TemplateID)
    {
        MyTemplate def = new MyTemplate();
        //If I uncomment this line the build will fail
        //this = def.GetInstance(TemplateID);
    }

    public Instance()
    {
    }
}

class MyTemplate
{
    public Instance GetInstance(int TemplateID)
    {
        Instance inst = new Instance();
        //Find the template in the DB and get some values
        inst.name = String.Format("From template: {0}", TemplateID.ToString());
        return inst;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to be able to do anything other than create a new object just from the code in the constructor, don't use a constructor in the first place.

Do you really need an Instance constructor taking an int? Why not turn it into a static factory method:

```
public static Instance CreateInstance(int id)
{
    MyTemplate def = new MyTemplate();
    return def.GetInstance(id);
}
```

Static methods have various advantages over constructors - although some disadvantages too. (There's a [separate SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194496) on that - worth a look.)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot recreate 'this' from either the constructor or any other method. You can create another object and copy contents, but I would instead make the factory public. Define a factory class that has three createDocument() methods, one for a blank document, one for a document from the DB and a third one from a template:

```
public class Factory {
   public static Document createBlankDocument();
   public static Document createDocument( DocumentId id );
   public static Document createDocumentFromTemplate( TemplateId id );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm with Jon, it is much better to use factory methods as this is crystal clear to the developer about what is happening (something *more* than just creating a new object).

A factory method says to the programmer, "there's some special initialisation happening here, where using **new** will not be good enough".

Typically you will use factories when you want to recycle or cache resources, and as a converse you do not expect a recycled or cached resource when you use the **new** keyword; you expect a brand new resource (it's baked right into the keyword) :)

Comment: How often is it really advantageous to the caller to have a *compiler-enforced* guarantee that `new Fizzle` will return a new instance of `Fizzle` rather than a recycled instance of `Fizzle`, or an instance of some derived class, or `null`? I suspect that the main reason people use public constructors is simply that if construction of a `Fizzle` requires one parameter of type `string`, it's more convenient to declare a `public` constructor that takes one `string` than to define a `protected` constructor along with a `public` method that calls it.

Comment: @supercat the advantage is that you make it more intuitive for the developer and easier to maintain.  If you declare a new `FairlyComplicatedType` then modify it, and then realise that your other instance of `FairlyComplicatedType` was also modified, it'd be confusing for the poor developer who just wants a new instance of that type.  What should they call to get a new instance if `new` actually gets them an old instance?  Perhaps we could create a factory method called `GetNewFairlyComplicatedTypeForRealThisTimeHonest`.

Comment: Just as a factory method can either be broken or work correctly, so too with a constructor.  The compiler can guarantee that the return of the constructor will be a non-aliased reference to an object of a particular exact type, but it can't guarantee that the object will be usable in any way.  The only one of the above not guaranteed by a *non-broken* mutable-class factory which isn't called something like `TryCreateFoo()` would be the *exact* type of the object; a non-broken factory could return an object of another type iff that other type was 100% compatible with the declared type.

Comment: I never mentioned the compiler, all I'm trying to say is write code that is easy for your developers to understand (preferably without any "gotcha" features).

Comment: There are a few corner cases where it may be helpful to have a compiler guarantee that a new immutable type instance will be disjoint from any other (an immutable-class factory that knows of an instance whose properties would match one that's made to order would generally be allowed to return the existing instance), but I suspect that for 99% of types, such situations would represent less than 1% of the constructor calls.

Comment: If I see a call to `SomeMutableType.Create()`, I'm going to expect that to create a new instance which I could treat in every way, outside Reflection, as `SomeMutableType`.  If I see `myString = new String('!', 3)`, it will not be clear whether the caller actually needs a new string instance, or whether a reference to interned string `"!!!!!"` would suffice; by contrast, if code does `myString = "!!!!!".Copy();` it will be much clearer that it definitely wants a new string instance.