# Generating MySQLCommand Strings

Tags: c#, mysql

Is there a proper way to generate a valid MySQL string, and then pass values through a MySqlCommand?

I currently use a method like this one, and just stack more and more conditions on if I need more columns searched. It looks so gross I'd assume there's a better way of accomplishing the same thing.

```
private static string SelectUser(User u)
{
    bool and = false;
    string cmd = "SELECT * FROM `database`.`users` WHERE ";

    if (u.ID != null)
    {
        cmd += "`UserID` LIKE @0";
        and = true;
    }
    if (u.Username != null)
    {
        if (and) { cmd += " AND "; }
        cmd += "`Username` LIKE @1";
        and = true;
    }
    if (u.Role != null)
    {
        if (and) { cmd += " AND "; }
        cmd += "`Role` LIKE @1";
        and = true;
    }
    if (u.Department != null)
    {
        if (and) { cmd += " AND "; }
        cmd += "`Departments` LIKE @1";
        and = true;
    }
    if (u.Template != null)
    {
        if (and) { cmd += " AND "; }
        cmd += "`Template` LIKE @1";
        and = true;
    }

    return cmd;
}
```

I've found a few methods that almost work, like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6239659/5179030), but none of them allow me to modularly pass the values through `MySqlCommand.Parameters`.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to try.

First, do this:

```
   const string baseQuery = "SELECT * from database WHERE 1=1 AND ";
```

Then do

```
   var andClauses = new List<string>();
   if (U.id != null)  andClauses.Add("UserID = @0");
   if (U.username != null)  andClauses.Add("Username = @1");
   /* more like this */
   var query = baseQuery + string.Join (" AND ", andClauses);
```

That will get you a concatenated set of ANDs in your query. It's a little cleaner looking than what you have in your question.

Another trick to consider:  Write your query like this

```
const string baseQuery = @"
     SELECT whatever
       FROM mytable
      WHERE (userid = @0 OR @0 <= 0)
        AND (username = @1 OR LENGTH(@1) <= 0)
        AND (department = @2 OR LENGTH(@department) <= 0) ";
```

These `(column = @val OR @val <= 0)` WHERE-clauses let you put in an empty string or a zero integer to effectively skip the clause.

The `string = @"value";` construct lets you write a multiline string in c# -- incredibly handy for formatting your queries in a way where you have a chance of reading them.