# "Too many parameters" keep private variables or replace them by the parameter class

Tags: c#, data-structures

My question is not "what to do with too many parameters", I found the answer in [How to avoid "too many parameters" problem in API design?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239373/how-to-avoid-too-many-parameters-problem-in-api-design). what I need is a complement of informations about the implementation.

I had a class

```
internal class SomeClass
{
    private string value1;
    private DateTime value2;
    private SomeEnum value3;
    // and the same until valueALot

    internal SomeClass(string val1, DateTime val2, SomeEnum val3, ...)
    { }
 }
```

And I replaced the constructor parameters with a new class SomeParameters

```
internal class SomeParameters
{
    internal string value1 { get; set; }
    internal DateTime value2 { get; set; }
    internal SomeEnum value3 { get; set; }
}

internal class SomeClass
{
    internal SomeClass(SomeParameters parameters)
    { }
}
```

My question is: In the `SomeClass` class should I keep individual variables and assign them from SomeParameters or should I replace them with an instance of the `SomeParameters` class?

Solution 1:

```
internal class SomeClass
{
    private string value1;
    private DateTime value2;
    private SomeEnum value3;

    internal SomeClass(SomeParameters parameters)
    {
        value1 = parameters.value1;
        value2 = parameters.value2;
        value3 = parameters.value3;
    }
}
```

Solution 2:

```
internal class SomeClass
{
    private SomeParameters _parameters;

    internal SomeClass(SomeParameters parameters)
    {
        _parameters = parameters;
    } 
}
```

Solution 2 seems more easy and avoid redundance, but I don't know if it's a good practice. Is solution 2 could implies security problems?

Maybe the simplest solution is the good one and I'm asking myself too much questions.

Thanks for your feedbacks

Comment: The way you are presenting it, it seems like `SomeClass` *is* the parameter wrapper object, which makes `SomeParameters` rather redundant.

Comment: If you keep the values in a `SomeParameters` instance, you should make a copy of that instance. Otherwise the user of the class may later change the values in the given instance (`SomeParameters` is a reference type) and you may not want the values in your class to be changed from outside.

Comment: @Abion47 So I present it bad, SomeClass do a lot of stuff and is not a wrapper

Comment: @RenéVogt I agree, in the solution 2 the _parameters variable is a copy to avoid changes from outside

Answer (score 0):

Your SomeParameters is in fact a Data Transfer Object:

> When you're working with a remote interface, such as Remote Facade (388), each call to it is expensive. As a result you need to reduce
>   the number of calls, and that means that you need to transfer more
>   data with each call. One way to do this is to use lots of parameters.
>   However, this is often awkward to program - indeed, it's often
>   impossible with languages such as Java that return only a single
>   value.

https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html

I would say that there's nothing wrong with your solution 2, but I would like to know more about the context of your application and the business related to your SomeClass.

Also worths a reading: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649585.aspx