# BingInteger(long) has private acces in BigInteger

Tags: java, private, biginteger

Can someone explain me why I get this error?

```
    public BigInteger getTotalIDIDirecto(){
          BigInteger totalIDI = new BigInteger(0);
          return totalIDI;

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor `BigInteger(long)` is limited to `private` access and [used internally](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/math/BigInteger.java#BigInteger.%3Cinit%3E%28long%29). You can use

```
BigInteger totalIDI = BigInteger.ZERO;
```

Comment: For this particular case `BigInteger.ZERO` might be a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

That Constructor does not exist in the API.

See
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

You may want to use [the valueOf static method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#valueOf(long)).

Answer (score 0):

Because that constructor is private. You have to use `BigInteger.valueOf(long)` instead.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#valueOf(long)

Pro and cons of static constructor are discussed here
[Static factory methods vs Instance (normal) constructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194496/static-constructors-vs-instance-normal-constructors)