# What are the new features of C# v4.0?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [New Cool Features of C# 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292265/new-cool-features-of-c-4-0)

Hello,

There are several(many) questions at SO about "what do you want in C# v4.0?". This question is different,I'm not asking you what you'd like to see in the new version of Microsoft's baby,but what is already in there since Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Beta 1 is already out.

I myself found only optional parameters implemented in VS2010.

```
void foo(int a,int b = 10)
{
    if(b != 10) throw new Exception();
}

void Main(string[] args)
{
    foo(5);
    foo(5,6);
}
```

Its very hard for me to find every single thing in that huge language,because I don't know what's planned to be implemented.All I've seen is those "What do you want in C# 4?" questions,which doesn't help my progress to grow up.

What new feature have you found in VS2010 Beta1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [C# Future page @ MSDN](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfuture/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1686) you'll find a documentation of the new features which were added to the Beta1 version of C# 4.0, along with samples.

Answer (score 1):

You are really asking two separate questions:

> What new feature have you found in
>   Vs2010 Beta1?

This would be new IDE features, not language features. I do not know much about these, but I do know that the IDE has been rewritten in WPF and will have better support for multi-monitor. There is an article about other new features [here](http://www.codeguru.com/vb/vbnet30/article.php/c15645/). If you are doing XML/XSLT, the new XSLT debugging feature is neat.

> What new features are in C# 4.0 ?

The biggest new feature is propably dynamic programming via the ["dynamic" keyword](http://blogs.msdn.com/cburrows/archive/2008/10/27/c-dynamic.aspx). There are also optional parameters, which you mention yourself.

Beyond that, the most important new feature is likely to be contravariance and covariance in generics. I will not try to explain it here, since it would be quite lengthy, but do see [Eric Lippert's blog for a thorough explanation](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/16/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-one.aspx). He has a whole series on the subject, and it gets explained in detail.

Comment: +1 for the dynamic type keyword, for doing dynamic binding