# C# 3.0 In A Nutshell and C# 4.0

Tags: c#

I purchased C# 3.0 In A Nutshell a few years ago and never completed it.  I'm trying to get back into C# and noticed C# 4.0 is out.  I'm wondering how 'dated' the book is now or if its just a matter of there being a few more features to worry about learning later with 4.0?  Also, I'm very interested in getting into LINQ in depth so changes there are particularly relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# 3 in a nutshell is a great book for learning a lot about c#, and I remember there being enough information on Linq as well.

I would continue reading the book you have, and just read some articles and blog posts on the new features of c# 4 to get into it.

...by the way, one of the best ways I found learning about new features or "cool" features in a certain programming language or tool is by looking for the "what are the coolest features of ... ?" questions on StackOverflow.
For example, there's this question about [cool features in C# 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292265/new-cool-features-of-c-4-0)

Answer (score 1):

The main new things in C# 4 are the dynamic keyword, covariance/contravariance and optional parameters. There isn't much that's been deprecated.

Unlike the huge leap from C# 1 to C# 2 or C# 2 to C# 3, you can grasp all of C# 4's new features in a couple hours. Dynamic idioms might take a while to get used to, but there's plenty of resources on that, and it's not exactly essential.

So yeah, a C# 3 book is still perfectly good.