# DateTime.Now as parameter value C#

Tags: c#

I have a method that has a parameter of type DateTime that must not be in the past, which indicates when some other stuff executes. So naturally I want to use this method and pass DateTime.Now to it, so that everything happens as soon as possible.

The problem here is that DateTime.Now at the time of the call and DateTime.Now at the time it is actually checked will probably be different values, so how do I make sure that the date is not in the past, yet allow the method to be called with something like DateTime.Now? I don't want to add magic numbers here, but a general solution.

**UPDATE.** I've found this question [How frequent is DateTime.Now updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307582/how-frequent-is-datetime-now-updated-or-is-there-a-more-precise-api-to-get-the)

Comment: There is no magical solution, change your design...
- DoIt(DateTime when)
- DoItNow()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to me that you have two options:

1. Add an appropriate small amount of time on to now (1 second say) so that you'll trigger things almost immediately. This will work, but its not nice.
2. Add another method (overload) that doesn't take a time parameter but instead actions immediately e.g.

   DoAction(attime); - will do the action at the stated time

   DoAction(); - will do the action now

The latter is a nicer solution but obviously there may be issues with how/where the method is available for use (and assumes you can add the method anyway).

Comment: So it seems there are just these two options. I was just thinking there could be others.

Comment: As you are not in a real time environment, I wouldn't advice option 1. You may have issue with option 2 but you DO have an issue with option 1.

Comment: +1 for the DateTime-less overload option. I think that's the cleanest way to handle this situation. Saves the caller from having to type DateTime.Now all the time.

Comment: Third option would be to introduce a small amount of tolerance into the action method i.e. to not reject times in the past if they are less than however long in the past - but that would be hidden from view, if you do the add in the parameter its *obvious* that you're pushing the boundaries and you won't end up with the philosophical argument. In which case one has to suggest that if you are able then the overload solution is surely the most elegant!

Comment: @Guillaume - question in that case becomes whether there are issues with sequential processing i.e. does this have to happen before that.

Answer (score 4):

If you want everything to happen as soon as possible why don't you rewrite your method to run as soon as it's called, or create an overload without the DateTime parameter to run as soon as it's called.

Using the overload of course would allow you to run your code at a time in the future (using the DateTime overload) or immediately.

Comment: And in the overload, if someone uses a time in the past, to bad for them :p

Comment: I'm sure you'll agree that regardless of whether or not he overloads his method, if a DateTime in the past causes a problem he needs to check for this and possibly throw an exception (perhaps ArgumentOutOfRangeException or ArgumentException).

Answer (score 3):

It's a philosophical problem - DateTime.Now is always in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Compare the parameter on entry to DateTime.Now. If it's in the past, then use DateTime.Now.

Alternately, don't use a parameter; just use DateTime.Now.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to have some sort of tolerance when testing if the time is close enough.

Answer (score 1):

Let your function take a `Nullable<DateTime>`. Interpret a null time to mean "do this immediately".

Answer (score 1):

If you check that the passed DateTime parameter is equal to or greater than DateTime.Now at the beginning of the function, it is extremely unlikely that the system time would have changed between the time the function was called with DateTime.now and when the check is made.  The system time is only updated every 10 or 15 milliseconds, and the actual function call time is much less than that.

To be sure that this *never* happens, however, you would have to check the passed time against `DateTime.Now.Subtract(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 25))`, which would give the slight possibility of a time a little bit in the past being accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Throw an ArgumentException if your date arg is in the past?  This seems the simplest.

Comment: That's the whole point of my question. User will pass DateTime.Now and get the exception, because DateTime.Now at the time of execution will be different.

Answer (score 0):

For the parameter, use a delegate returning a `DateTime` value. When calling the function, pass in a delegate pointing to a function that returns `DateTime.Now`.

Comment: Nice! People will probably hate me if I do this, but I like it.

Comment: @HeavyWave: *I* would hate you for doing this.

Comment: On second thoughts, I think even in this case the time values will be different at the time they are checked... so I downvote my own answer. But SO says I can't downvote my own answer! Weird.

Comment: @Agnel: I down-voted you at your request. I like being at multiples of 5, anyway. :)

Comment: @MusiGenesis: Thanks. :) I like being at multiples of 3283.