# Changing Qt's timer resolution on Windows

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-7, timer, qt4

I have an application, written with Qt 4.8, that uses Qt's timer facilities to trigger periodic events at regular intervals (via `QObject::startTimer()`, with events posted to the owning `QThread`'s message queue). Qt sets up timers on Windows by ultimately calling the Windows API function `SetTimer`.

The default resolution on Windows is 15.6ms. I need a period of 20ms +/- 0.5ms. However, when I specify 20ms, I am actually getting 31.2ms (+/- 0.02ms). When I specify 10ms (just for kicks), I am getting 15.6ms. This is all consistent with the default resolution. I need the resolution to be some factor of 19.5-20.5 (e.g. 0.5, 1, 2, 4, 5, 10, even 20).

I tried using `timeBeginPeriod`/`timeEndPeriod`, which reported success, but had no effect - I think this only applies to winmm timers and not `SetTimer`.

Qt timers are at the mercy of the underlying timer resolution for the platform, so I do have to go over its head.

Is there some way I can set the resolution of `SetTimer`? I'm OK with making Windows-specific API calls. I'm also OK with doing it globally, even if it comes down to a registry hack. The application is running on a dedicated Windows 7 machine, and system-wide negative effects of changing the timer resolution globally are inconsequential.

Comment: I almost wonder if I should ask this on SU instead...

Comment: It turns out `SetTimer` cannot be set for a period less than **10ms** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @AndrewDunn Yeah; I've clarified my question even further. I actually need a period of 19.5-20.5ms, which I can't achieve with the 15.6ms resolution.

Comment: Are you running an optimized build? You could be getting overhead

Comment: @AndrewDunn I am. I also am seeing the same results in a minimal test program that just starts a periodic timer and prints the time deltas (using the performance counter). It is very consistent with the 15.6ms default resolution; I am seeing multiples of 15.6ms +/- 0.02ms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Qt documentation about `QObject::startTimer(int interval, Qt::TimerType timerType = Qt::CoarseTimer)` :

> Note that QTimer's accuracy depends on the underlying operating system
>   and hardware. The timerType argument allows you to customize the
>   accuracy of the timer. See Qt::TimerType for information on the
>   different timer types. Most platforms support an accuracy of 20
>   milliseconds; some provide more. If Qt is unable to deliver the
>   requested number of timer events, it will silently discard some.

I think that you can set timer type to `Qt::PreciseTimer`. On Windows, Qt will use [Windows's Multimedia timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd742877%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) facility (if available) for this type which has a resolution of 1 millisecond.

Comment: Alas, I am using Qt 4.8, and the timer precision appears to be a new feature of Qt 5. This is certainly a compelling reason to upgrade though; it's good to see they addressed it. Thanks for pointing this out I would have had no idea it existed.

Comment: Accepting this old answer because I upgraded away from Qt4 long ago and Qt5 has much more capable timer facilities.

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to use a resolution less than **10ms** using `SetTimer`. If you try to use a lower value, Windows will simply use 10ms instead.

Have you considered using the `QElapsedTimer` instead? It uses Windows' high resolution performance counter by default and falls back to a less precise timer if not available.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qelapsedtimer.html

Comment: Thanks; the `QElapsedTimer` resolution is sufficient but I am actually using the timers to trigger periodic events, and the application is designed to handle timer events posted to the owner `QThread`'s message queue. Unfortunately, to minimize the damage I'd have to create a new thread to manage timing and do a bit of refactoring that I'd like to avoid (and if I do that I might as well just use winmm timers so I don't burn CPU looping). I've edited my question to clarify that I'm driving periodic events rather than measuring elapsed time.

Comment: I don't know about Qt, but this is false / obsolete when it comes to Win7+. [A simple test proves that it can go down to 1ms](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4962857/33080).