# .NET Is there a way to get the parent thread id?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Suppose the main thread is spawning a new thread t1, how can my code that runs on t1 find the thread id of the main thread (using c#)?

Edit:
I don't control the creation of the new thread. So I can't pass any parameters to the thread.

Thanks.

Comment: Fundamentally all threads in a process under Win32 are equal, there is no "main thread". .NET adds the refinement of background threads, but there is still no "main thread".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't.

Yet you might consider:

1. Prefix the name of the new thread with the thread ID from the parent thread
2. Create a constructor on the method you want to spawn that requires the thread ID from the parent

Answer (score 2):

If you only have two threads and the second thread is a background thread you can enumerate all threads in the process and eliminate the background thread by reading the [`Thread.IsBackground` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx). Not very pretty but perhaps what you need?

You can read more about [foreground and background threads on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h339syd0.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have a property to do that, but you could add a new parameter to your thread an pass to it. It would be the easiest way I could think of...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Threadpool (thus no control over the creation of Threads here) you could work as follows:

```
private static void myfunc(string arg)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Thread "
                     + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId
                     + " with parent " + Thread.GetData(Thread.GetNamedDataSlot("ParentThreadId")).ToString()
                     + ", with argument: " 
                     + arg
                     );
}
public static int Main(string[] args)
{
    var parentThreadId = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
    WaitCallback waitCallback = (object pp) =>
    {
        Thread.SetData(Thread.GetNamedDataSlot("ParentThreadId"), parentThreadId);
        myfunc(pp.ToString());
    };

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(waitCallback, "my actual thread argument");
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    return 0;
}
```

This would produce something like:

```
 Thread 3 with parent 1, with argument: my actual thread argument
```

If however there is no way to pass data to the child thread at all, consider renaming the parent thread, or alternatively all the child threads.