# C# sorted LinkedList

Tags: unity-game-engine, c#-3.0

It seems I'm not able to find the C# (C# 3.0 I'm using Unity3D) collection I need:

1. I need to be able to **add and remove items quickly while iterating** like in a `LinkedList`.
2. I need to **sort** it frequently several times like `Sort` in `List` (interested in any of mergesort, quicksort and radixsort)
3. I need to sort according to **different sort functions** because I have to sort according to different fields like Name, Surname etc. (so `SortedList` or `SortedDictionary` no good).

List, seems "almost correct" apart the fact it is in reality an array and I cannot remove items randomly while iterating forward.

LinkedList would be perfect but miss sorting ability (for a linkedlist would be natural mergesort, wich is in addition stable, may need it to be a stable sort, not required for now).

The best bet would be finding that actually a .NET sorting method already exists for LinkedList and I'm not aware of it.

If I would have time of implementing such class myself I would go for a LinkedList with a method for sorting using a mergesort and a custom lambda as comparer, however seems that stuff is missing from .NET?

Comment: I fear that will be too slow.. or no?

Comment: not as slow as alternatives

Comment: So if no alternatives or slow alternativs I fear I'll have to code that myself U.U

Comment: You should know that linq is not fully supported for ios, OrderBy and OrderByDescending do not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Linq!**

> 1. I need to be able to add and remove items quickly while iterating like in a LinkedList.

use the linq `collection.RemoveAll(item => {conditions} );`

> 2. I need to sort it frequently several times like Sort in List (interested in any of mergesort, quicksort and radixsort)

use the linq `.OrderBy(item => item.Field).ThenBy(item => item.OtherField).ThenByDescending(item => item.OmgAnotherField);`

> 3. I need to sort according to different sort functions because I have to sort according to different fields like Name, Surname etc. (so
>      SortedList or SortedDictionary no good).

see #2

Comment: For the uninitiated, this requires a reference to Linq as thus: `using System.Linq;`

Comment: It also increases the chances of obscure IL2CPP errors when you build to iOS from Unity.

Comment: I accept the answer but actually it is not what I need, it is still the minor evil, the imputed code is already the bottleneck, it is possible I have to roll my own implementation in future if the bottleneck become worse.

Comment: RemoveAll is not LINQ, btw