# C# objects and C++ objects, the difference

Tags: c#, c++, pointers

When creating an object instance as such in C#

```
Myclass mc = new Myclass();
```

This `mc` is now a reference to a `Myclass` object created in memory.  It's like a 'pointer' to that memory.

Is it the same or comparable to doing this in (Managed or Unmanaged) C++:

```
MyCppClass *mcCppClass = new MyCppClass();
```

Because this actually creates a pointer to an object instance of the class.

I'm just trying to find out what exactly the differences are?

Comment: So the C++ pointer could point to an already existing object in memory as well as create a new object in memory.  Though you can do that in C# as well...  When would you create a reference in C++ to an object then and would you create a pointer to that object?

Comment: In my experience, references are usually used when passing arguments to functions.  If you have an object and pass it by value, the object is copied, which can be expensive depending on what the copy constructor and destructor do.  However, if you pass it as a reference, you avoid the cost of the copy constructor and destructor calls.  It's typically more efficient.

Comment: Sorry for sounding silly, but a C# reference can then reference any object of the same type.  Because one can change an object reference in C#.  A reference in C++ always points to the same instance of whatever it's referencing.  Right?

Comment: @Tony:  Right.  A C++ reference is a different name for an object (using the term loosely), and you can't change which object.  C++ has constructs to do anything a C# reference will do (including automatic destruction) but not in the same packaging.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An important difference, which no one seems to have mentioned yet, is this:

```
Myclass mc = new Myclass();
```

in C#, this is the *only* correct way to create a new object. When you need an object, this is how you create it.

```
MyCppClass *mcCppClass = new MyCppClass();
```

In C++, this is how you *can* create an object, and how you *occasionally* have to create an object. The problem with using this approach in C++ is that:

- `new` is extremely slow in C/C++, compared to a managed language. If used to allocate every object you need, it's going to hurt.
- The object has no fixed lifetime. It is allocated on the heap, and it is not destroyed until you call `delete` on it. If you forget to do so, it is never destroyed. If you call `delete` twice, your program blows up.

In C++, you have two ways to create objects:
The one you used above:

```
// 1
MyCppClass *myobject = new MyCppClass();
delete myobject;
```

*but modified to include the `delete` call as well, because without it, you're leaking memory.* Whenever you use `new`, you must also, sooner or later, call `delete`. One without the other is, in general, an error.

And the second, more common, approach:

```
// 2
MyCppClass myobject;
```

The second one is, in some ways, more similar to your C# example. Its lifetime is automatically managed by the system (although the way it is managed is different. In C++, it lasts until it goes out of scope, where in C# it lasts until no one references it and it gets garbage collected - but in both cases, you don't have to do anything to ensure it is destroyed). It is also, in general, the *correct* way to create object instances, for the same reason.

One of the most common mistakes made by new C++ programmers is to use `new` to allocate every object, store pointers to them, and then *try* to remember to delete them. A simpler, more robust and more efficent solution is to avoid `new` and avoid pointers as far as possible. Occasionally, you need an object whose lifetime is not limited to the declaring scope, (and where copying the object isn't an option for using it outside that scope). Then you use `new`, and most likely, wrap the resulting pointer in a smart pointer of some type.

Comment: A simple technique for new C++ programmers is to use smart pointers instead of raw pointers.  Just making every pointer into a `std::tr1::shared_ptr<>` will solve a whole lot of problems.  It isn't the right thing to do all the time, but it'll work well enough and is an easy rule to remember.

Comment: I would rather mention that the C# pointer is more like a boost::shared_ptr in C++. That would give it the same use semantics in both languages. It is unfair to think of objects in the two languages being the same (semantically they look the same) but there is a lot of extra compiler work happening on the C# object that is not done on the C++ pointer.

Comment: I disagree that stack allocation is more common with custom objects than heap allocation is.  Also, you skipped over the difference between reference and value types.  'a = b' has very different meaning in C# depending on whether a and b are reference or value types.

Comment: On the first part, you are (or should be) wrong. Among C++ programmers *who know what they're doing*, heap allocation is rare. When it happens it is typically wrapped inside a stack-allocated RAII object -- as `std::vector` does. You're right that I skipped over .NET's value types. The reason is that they're *mostly* irrelevant to this answer. They don't exactly fit what I said about lifetime lasting until the object gets GC'ed, but the semantics of `a = b` has nothing to do with this answer, so I don't see why I should have mentioned that.

Comment: The semantics of `a = b` is relevant because Tony states "Because this actually creates a pointer to an object instance of the class." This implies he does not yet understand the difference between reference and value types.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you are responsible for deleting that memory, whereas in C# you are not. That's probably the biggest difference you'll want to remember.

As far as the similarities, they are both heap-allocated objects.

[Here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rmcochran/csharp_memory01122006130034PM/csharp_memory.aspx) is a good article on heap vs stack in C# which you might find useful.

Answer (score 0):

They are equal in the sense that both `new` allocates memory for the member variables. They are different in that C++ (in your example) is a pointer to the object in memory and that C# has a reference (which is not a pointer, but not a C++ reference either, i.e., it can be null).

Both languages guarantee the result of `new` to be non-null, or throw an error (i.e. an `OutOfMemoryException` in C#).

Of course, the whole behavior of objects, classes etc is quite different in C++ and C# (garbage collection, auto-boxing behavior, static constructor etc).

*EDIT:* One thing not mentioned in the other answers yet: any `new` in C++ will call the constructor of the full hierarchy of classes. C# *is single-inheritance only* and will only call the first constructor in the hierarchy or the object ctor. In C#, if no constructors are defined, `new X()` is equal to `new object()`.

Answer (score 0):

They are similar, but there are some important caveats with the C# version:

- You create both value and reference objects with new Blah().  Value objects don't behave like reference objects: assigning them copies the data, not the reference.
- C# reference objects are garbage collected

Answer (score 0):

I think the C# version is more analagous to `reference` in this example:

```
MyCppClass *mcCppClass = new McCppClass();
MyCppClass &reference = *mcCppClass;
```

In C++, you don't have to worry about `reference` pointing to null, as it were.  It's just there, so you use it.  In C#, though, the object reference *can* be null.

Also, as @Kyle Walsh pointed out, you are responsible for deleting the memory associated with the `mcCppClass` pointer in C++.  In C#, your object will be garbage collected automatically.

One thing to be aware of is that C# makes a distinction between classes and structs.  Classes are reference types, while structs are value types.  In C++, classes and structs only differ in their default member visibility level (classes have private member visibility by default while structs have public member visibility by default).  This is an important distinction to note if moving from C++ to C#.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241134/what-is-the-worst-c-net-gotcha/640594#640594) for more details.

Comment: I agree to the similarity with references, and as you said, references cannot be null in C++. However, they *can* be null in C# ;-)

Comment: C# references are allowed to be `null`, whereas C++ references are not. Also C# references ensure that their targets will have a lifetime at least as long as every reference to it, whereas C++ references do not. They actually have very little in common. Just about the only common thing is that they can be used without special de-referencing syntax, and so use dot to access members.

Answer (score 0):

It might be called a reference, but it's handled as a pointer (it can be NULL). In C++ a reference can't be null, it always refer to the **same** instance.

In C++, there is a strong difference between references and pointers. And C# (or java's) "references" are closer to C++ pointers than to C++ references.

```
int a = 3;
int b = 2;
int & c = b; // c and b will alway refer to the same thing.
c = a;    
std::cout << b << std::endl; // shows 3

int * pa = new int(3);
int * pb = new int(2);
int * pc = pb;
pc = pb; // pc and pb are now refering to different things

std::cout << *pb << std::endl;// shows 2
```

In C++, you don't need to alloc your instances in the free store (« using new »). You can also declare them on the stack. In the later case, you don't have to worry about deleting them.