# C# naming convention for private members

Tags: c#, variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Naming convention for private fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540146/naming-convention-for-private-fields)

I read on msdn about C# naming conventions but they don't talk about naming private fields vs parameters.

```
public void SetAnimation(int framesX, int framesY)
{
    framesX = framesX; // the first one is private class member
    framesY = framesY;
}
```

I must name private field differently than a parameter. I can't do camel case for both.
What do you suggest?

Comment: This has got to be a duplicate I've seen this question so many times.

Comment: How about prefixing with `_` for the private vars

Answer (score 5):

You can have same name. To have it more elegant, you can have:

```
this.framesX = framesX; // the first one is private class member
this.framesY = framesY;
```

Comment: Only the first one is a private class member (as suggested with the comment), therefore i assume the declaration of framesY is omitted on the posted code (and this.framesY would not compile)

Comment: I don't think he was trying to assign the parameter to itself.

Answer (score 3):

I generally do:

```
private int _framesX;
private int _framesY;
```

That makes it more clear:

```
public void SetAnimation(int framesX, int framesY)
{
    _framesX = framesX;
    _framesY = framesY;
}
```

Comment: I think it's more appropriate to put the underscores on the parameter names.

Comment: I like this more rather than using this.

Comment: Yes, but the naming convention for C# recommends not using underscores.

Comment: Yes they say don't use underscores.

Comment: @All - why are you making this complex, why change the name of something when you know for sure that it makes sense not to change it.  Use `this`, it's very much legit and the right way.

Comment: They recommended it originally, but a lot of their code goes against this very thing.

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on the company you work at. Basically a naming convention is a team rule and for example, Resharper allows you to add a team convention

Answer (score 0):

You can name it the same, but if referring to the private member you have to use

```
this.framesX;
```

So for example;

```
this.framesX = framesX;
```

Answer (score 0):

I normaly name my private fields (are there others ;) ) with a '_' prefixed. For some people this is a smell others do the same - I guess it's a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

I use _framesX for marking private fields.

Answer (score 0):

You could go with the "_" prefix for private members or use "this.framesX" or both "this._framesX".

I'd say it depents on what your team is using.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, you might need to specify `this` thought.
Well thats how I name my Fields and parameters mostly.

```
public void SetAnimation(int framesX, int framesY)
{
    this.framesX = framesX; // the first one is private class member
    this.framesY = framesY;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

private variables should start with lowercase. so you've got that right.

you can make yr code work by using 'this' keyword to refer back to the instantiated object.

```
public void SetAnimation(int framesX, int framesY)
{
    this.framesX = framesX; // the first one is private class member
    this.framesY = framesY;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a tendency to use only properties starting with a capital, and define the getter and setter public or private

```
public int FramesX { public get; private set; }
public int FramesY { get; set; }
```