# Difference between Property and Method

Tags: c#, properties, methods

Which one is better to use when it come to return value for example

```
public int EmployeeAge
{
    get{return intEmployeeAge};
}
```

And

```
public int EmployeeAge()
{
    return intEmployeeAge;
}
```

Which one is better and why? And what is best programming practice to use when we have secnario like above ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Properties are a useful way of expressing a feature of an object, allowing get/set in a common way that can be used by APIs like data-binding, reflection and serialization. So for simple *values* of the object, properties are handy. Properties can't take arguments, should not have significant side-effects*, and should return quickly and repeatably. Also, there is no such thing as an "extension property" (to mirror an extension method) nor a generic property.

(*=lazy loading etc isn't uncommon, however)

Methods (C# doesn't have functions) are better for expressing things that either *change* the state, or which have an expectation of taking some time and not necessarily being reproducible. They don't tend to work in binding / serialization etc.

Note that properties are actually just a special way of writing methods. There is little *functional* difference. It is all about expressing intent. The one thing you *don't* want to expose, however, is *fields* (the actual `intEmployeeAge` instance variable).

So I would have:

```
public int EmployeeAge { get{return intEmployeeAge}; }
```

or just (if on the `Employee` object):

```
public int Age { get{return intEmployeeAge}; }
```

Of course... then the question becomes "in what unit?" I assume that is years?

Comment: /agreed.
In a simple way, properties are designed to expose private fields outside the class to ensure no breaking changes if the class architecture is revised.

Comment: @JoeBilly - well, you can do a *bit* more than that without it getting too messy. But simple is as simple does, so they say.

Comment: Sure it was popularized. I mean you can do a lot of thing with a proeprty (good or bad) but it is an accessor first.

Comment: coming from java, it seems like c# properties act like mutator and accessor methods. Is this a correct assumption? If so, is there a point of having methods in C# to get instance variables when properties do so? Please correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: @Ben you are correct. And the `get` / `set` **are** methods. Behind the scenes, that is actually `get_Age` and `get_EmployeeAge`

Answer (score 9):

If all you need to do is return a value, use a property.

If you need to *do* something before returning a value, use a function.

Comment: But in case of property I can also add some processing what you call it "do something" before return value in property as well, in above case both are returning value. but which is better ?

Comment: Yes, you can, but you need to think about _meaning_. Most programmers, when calling a property do not expect it to change object state, but when calling a function they do expect this.

Answer (score 5):

Properties holds object data

Functions defines object behavior

Take a look at -> [Property Usage Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bzwdh01d%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

> *Which one is better and why? And what is best programming practice to use when we have 
>   secnario like above ?*

I write in C# however I prefer to use Get/Set functions, for me it's just better way to express what I can get from object and how I can change it's state (and this methods are grouped by alphabet in Intelisense which is also nice). However, if team prefers other conventions it's not a problem but when I work on my own projects it's just easier to read API.

```
e.g

Obejct1 o = new Object1();
o.P1;
o.P2;
o.P3;
```

from looking to API you can't say what you change in a public API or what it a read only property, unless you use IDE that shows you a small icon showing actually what you can do.

```
Object1 o = new Object1();
o.GetP1();
o.SetP2();
o.SetP3();
```

One can easily find from API how data can be changed by type's clients.

Answer (score 1):

A method returns values after work is completed and a value is the result of the work being done. I don't think this is what you are doing.

A property (accessor) is meant for returning variables, which seems to be what you're trying to achieve:

As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287786(VS.71).aspx):

> The accessor of a property contains
>   the executable statements associated
>   with getting (reading or computing) or
>   setting (writing) the property. The
>   accessor declarations can contain a
>   get accessor, a set accessor, or both.
>   The declarations take the following
>   forms:

```
public int EmployeeAge
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Have a [look here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287786(VS.71).aspx), as it gives a very good description on the uses of these.

Answer (score 1):

Property is a way explore the internal  data element of a class in a simple manner. We can implement a properties with the type-safe get and set method.Property is implicitly called using calling convention.Property works on compile and runtime.

Method is a block of code that contain a series of statements.Method is explicitly called.
Methods works on runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little late to this party, but I'll just mention another surprising difference between a property and a parameterless "get" method.  As @MarcGravell notes, lazy loading is a common pattern when using properties, but beware of the [Heisenberg Watch Window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2245370/7850) gotcha!

Answer (score 0):

I think this has a lot to do with the culture you are programming in. As I see it, the C# / .NET culture would **prefer to use a property** for this case.

My advice: Try to be consistent with the main libraries you are using.

**BUT:** Be wary of using properties (or functions that serve the same purpose, as in your example above), as they are often a sign of bad design. You want to *tell* your objects to do stuff, as opposed to *asking* them for information. Don't be religious about this, though, just be aware of this as a code smell.

Comment: Culture? didn't get your point, as In both cases it onlye return employee age.

Comment: By *culture* I mean the body of code that comes with a language / platform, the community of developers using them and the libraries they create.

Comment: I don't understand your code smell reference.  A complicated object might have many properties especially if it has multiple ancestors...

Comment: @Dining Philanderer: Sure it can. But be wary of such objects. Make sure you are certain that it needs to be what it is, since having lots of properties could be a sign of bad design. Properties tend to create dependencies and complicated if/else code.