# color and file dialog different operator signs

Tags: vb.net

examples:

1. picturebox1.backcolor = colordialog1.color
2. picturebox1.load(openfiledialog1.filename)

question:
Why does number one use a = sign and number two use parenthesis to use the dialog result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number one is a [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/65zdfbdt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and number two a method.

[Difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2544729/284240)

- A **property** normally just gets/sets a private field in a class and should not have side-effects or be an expensive operation.
- A **method** in a class can be a procedure that performs some sort of operation on the data within the class.