# Exercise: Add a DateOfBirth property to your class

Tags: c#, .net

I am doing a tutorial series on .Net Academy and have run into a problem. They don't really have a useful help section so I was wondering if anyone here can help me. My issue is that I think I have done the code right, but I get this error:

> Not all requirements have been met.
>      You must declare a DateTime property named DateOfBirth

Here is my code:

```
using System;

public class Person
{
    public Person(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
    }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public int Age {get; set;}

    public string GetFullName()
    {
        return FirstName + " " + LastName;
    }

    public int DateOfBirth()
    {
        return DateTime.Now.AddYears(-Age).Year;
    }
}
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: You can google it how to add a DateTime property in class.

Comment: Your `DateOfBirth` is a method rather than a property and it is of type `int` not `DateTime`.

Comment: Also, note that `return DateTime.Now.AddYears(-Age).Year;` is quite a wrong implementation

Comment: Thanks everyone who gave me the correct solution!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare DateOfBirth as a property like this

```
public DateTime DateOfBirth {get; set;}
```

and age should be a caculated property instead like this

```
 public int Age 
        {
            get
               {
                return DateTime.Now.Year - DateOfBirth.Year;
               }    
        }
```

Comment: Thank you @ClearLogic for helping me.  That worked. I forgot to add what the assignment was:    "Add a DateOfBirth property to your class, which is of type DateTime."        I only needed the first part but seeing the second part too helped me understand even further. Thanks :)

Comment: Similarly you can convert `GetFullName` method into a getter only property `FullName`

Comment: Of course if you change `Age` to be a calculated property (which it should be, since it changes but dateofbirth never changes), then you'll need to change `DateOfBirth` to a regular (non-calculated) property. Otherwise you'll have both properties trying to calculate their value from the other and have an infinite loop.

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
public int DateOfBirth()
{
    return DateTime.Now.AddYears(-Age).Year;
}
```

is not a property, [but a *method*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544707/difference-between-property-and-method). You can easily turn it into a property though:

```
public int DateOfBirth
{
    get { return DateTime.Now.AddYears(-Age).Year; }
}
```

*See the documentation for a description of [properties in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties)*

You'll likely still run into issues since the type is `int` rather than the required `DateTime`. Skip the `.Year` reference and return the entire `DateTime` struct, and finally update the property signature:

```
public DateTime DateOfBirth
{
    get { return DateTime.Now.AddYears(-Age); }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a method called DateOfBirth, instead it should be a property like this:

```
public DateTime DateOfBirth
{
        get { return DateTime.Now.Date.AddYears(-Age); }
}
```

Notice the usage of .Date after now to get the Date and not the time part.