# Does using a lambda expression passed into a method slow down an Entity Framework query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, delegates, linq-to-entities

I have a method:

```
public static void GetObjects()
{
    using(MyContext context = new MyContext())
    {
         var objects = context.Bars.Where(b => b.Prop1 != null)
                       .Select(b => new MyObject{Prop = b.Prop1, Name = b.Name})
                       .ToList();
         foreach(var object in objects)
         {
             // do something with the object
         }
    }
}
```

I refactored the method to make it more general so that I can pass in a `Func` so that I can specify the `where` statement and what property from the `Bars` table gets assigned to `MyObject.Prop` like this:

```
public static void GetObjectsV2(Func<Bar, bool> whereFunc, Func<Bar, string> selectPropFunc)
{
    using(MyContext context = new MyContext())
    {
         var objects = context.Bars.Where(whereFunc)
                       .Select(b => new MyObject{Prop = selectPropFunc(b), Name = b.Name})
                       .ToList();
         foreach(var object in objects)
         {
             // do something with the object
         }
    }
}
```

`GetObjectsV2` seems to run much slower than `GetObjects`.  Are there any reasons this would affect performance, and if so, are there any ways around this while still keeping the function flexible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The reason it is running slower is because you are passing in a `Func<Bar, bool>` which forces the context to retrive ALL Bars and then run the Func on the returned result set.  A way to make this run better is to pass in `Expression<Func<Bar, bool>>`

Putting that all together will result in the following:

```
public static void GetObjectsV2(Expression<Func<Bar, bool>> whereFunc, Expression<Func<Bar, string>> selectPropFunc)
{
    using(MyContext context = new MyContext())
    {
         var objects = context.Bars.Where(whereFunc)
                       .Select(selectPropFunc)
                       .ToList();
         foreach(var object in objects)
         {
             // do something with the object
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As [I discovered in my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675536), `.Where(o => whereFunc(o))` is not the same as `.Where(whereFunc)` in the Entity Framework.

The first one, `.Where(Expression<Func<Bar, bool>>)` works like any other linq call, simply appending the expression to the expression tree.

In the second case, `.Where(Func<Bar, bool>>)`, it will compile and evaluate the linq call (which so far is just `context.Bars`) before applying the `whereFunc` predicate.

---

So, to answer your question, the second one is much slower because it is pulling the entire `Bars` table into memory before doing anything with it. Using `.Where(o => whereFunc(o))` instead should fix that

*(or, as Mark suggests, change the type of whereFunc to `Expression<Func<Bar, bool>>`, which `Func<Bar, bool>` is implicitly convertible to)*