# Entity Framework, Generic Repository Pattern and strange SQL generation

Tags: sql, entity-framework, repository, generics

I've implemented a generic repository for Entity Framework 4.  Here's a dumbed down version, where AllAppContainer is the EF4 object context:

```
public class Repository<T> where T : class
{
    protected AllAppContainer objectContext;
    protected ObjectSet<T> entitySet;

    public Repository()
    {
        objectContext  = new AllAppContainer();
        entitySet = objectContext.CreateObjectSet<T>();
    }

    public int QueryCount(Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        int queryCount = entitySet.Count(predicate);
        return queryCount;
    }
}
```

The one method is QueryCount(), which I want to act as a **select Count(*) ... where** line of SQL (not returning the actual records).

Straight-forward?  You'd think...  First, let's do a non-Repository version of the same thing, performing a count on Item entities:

```
AllAppContainer allAppContainer = new AllAppContainer();
int nonRepCount = allAppContainer.Items.Count(item => item.Id > 0);
```

SQL Server Profiler says the generated SQL is:

```
SELECT 
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
    FROM [dbo].[Items] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Id] > 0
)  AS [GroupBy1]
```

Woo-hoo! Score!

Now let's call the same using my Repository QueryCount:

```
Repository<Item> repository = new Repository<Item>();
int repCount = repository.QueryCount(item => item.Id > 0);
```

Here's the generated SQL:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[SmallField] AS [SmallField]
FROM [dbo].[Items] AS [Extent1]
```

Yep, EF is returning the full set of data, then calling *Count()* on it in-memory.

For fun I tried changing the relevant line in Repository QueryCount to:

```
int queryCount = new AllAppContainer().CreateObjectSet<T>().Count(predicate);
```

and the non-repository line to:

```
int nonRepCount = allAppContainer1.CreateObjectSet<Item>().Count(item => item.Id > 0);
```

but the generated SQL for each is the same as before.

Now why would all this repository-returns-all-matching-records-then-counts be happening, when it doesn't for non-repository?  And is there any way to do what I want via my generic repository i.e. count at db.  I can't take the in-memory count performance hit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to use `Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate` for your `Count` otherwise the framework uses the `Enumerable.Count<TSource> Method (IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, Boolean>)` which gets the whole collection from DB to be able to call for each item, so your method should be:

```
public int QueryCount(Expression<Func<T, Boolean>> predicate)
{
    int queryCount = entitySet.Count(predicate);
    return queryCount;
}
```

Comment: +1 see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855399 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675536 - I would almost call this a bug.

Comment: Wow, I'm not at work now, but I'll be running in tomorrow to check this out.  Thanks for the fast response K.  And thanks for the pointers BlueRaja - the frustrating thing was not knowing the terms to search for on this problem: mine and the other two questions have completely different titles/subjects, but apparently stem from the same thing.

Comment: @BlueRaja: What do you want to call a bug? Not fully understanding difference between IEnumerable<T> and IQueryable<T> is not a bug. It is a key knowledge you must have to correctly use Linq.

Comment: @Ladislav: This has nothing to do with the difference between `IQueryable<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>` - this is a bug in the Entity Framework.  I have yet to meet one person who would expect at first glance for `.Where(MyFunc)` and `.Where(o => MyFunc(o))` to have such completely different behavior.  When an API is incredibly and needlessly counter-intuitive like that, I call it a bug.

Comment: @BlueRaja: I don't agree. Moreover it has nothing to do with EF.