# FileInfo displaying a peculiar date

Tags: .net

Why does the following display 12/31/1600 ???

```
Imports System.IO

Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim fi As New FileInfo("DocFiles\phillips_phone_number.txt")
    Console.WriteLine(fi.FullName)
    Console.WriteLine(fi.LastAccessTime.ToShortDateString)
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```

End Module

Comment: December 31st, 1600 was the date the British East India Company was chartered. Do you have any Indian co-workers who like to play practical jokes?

Comment: That is so funny, I am Indian :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that code is not able to find the file, see the documentation for the GetLastAccessTime function in the SDK http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getlastaccesstime.aspx

It states,

> If the file described in the path
>   parameter does not exist, this method
>   returns 12:00 midnight, January 1,
>   1601 A.D. (C.E.) Coordinated Universal
>   Time (UTC), adjusted to local time.

Comment: OK, this one is a candidate for most bizarre .NET library behavior. Why would they return *anything* instead of throwing an exception here, and why return that date in particular? And why return an adjusted local time instead of UTC (making this condition much more difficult to check for)? This is weirder than .NET throwing an OutOfMemoryException when trying to load an invalid Image file.

Comment: This is a candidate for my .NET gotchas question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241134/what-is-the-worst-gotcha-in-c-or-net

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify the time you are seeing, only the date, but I suspect it is 23:00:00. If you use `Console.WriteLine(fi.LastAccessTime)`, you will likely see it print `-36000000000`.

The last-access-timestamp of the file is being returned as 0 either because, as Sijin [pointed out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.getlastaccesstime?view=net-6.0), the path is invalid, or because you have [disabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc785435%28v=ws.11%29) the [last-access update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-2000-server/cc959914%28v=technet.10%29) on an NTFS volume, or because you are using Vista or higher in which [it is disabled](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090217-00/?p=19123) [by default](http://windowsreference.com/windows-7/enabledisable-last-access-timestamp-in-windows/).

In any case, because [Windows uses January 1, 1601](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090306-00/?p=18913) as its [epoch base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)#Notable_epoch_dates_in_computing), a date of 0 would return `00:00:00 1601-01-01`.

Now why are you seeing it as December 31, 1600 instead? Simple: timezones. Your profile has no biographical information, but your name and the Latin quote in your biography section make it *not unreasonable* to guess that you may be living somewhere around Spain, which is in the timezone UTC+01:00. In this case, when the timestamp is adjusted to local time, it would take the time (0) as the base, and subtract one hour to convert it to your timezone. Thus, you get the value `-36000000000` which is `23:00:00 1600-12-31`.