# Why does TimeSpan.FromSeconds(double) round to milliseconds?

Tags: .net, timespan, base-class-library

`TimeSpan.FromSeconds` takes a double, and can represent values down to 100 nanoseconds, however this method inexplicably rounds the time to whole milliseconds.

Given that I've just spent half an hour to pinpoint this (documented!) behaviour, knowing why this might be the case would make it easier to put up with the wasted time.

Can anyone suggest why this seemingly counter-productive behaviour is implemented?

```
TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.12345678).TotalSeconds
    // 0.123
TimeSpan.FromTicks((long)(TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond * 0.12345678)).TotalSeconds
    // 0.1234567
```

Comment: I'm sorry to see the old answer go away.  I doubt I could come up with anything better (and I wanted to +1 it...)

Comment: "[K]nowing why this might be the case would make it easier to put up with the wasted time." Consider it a sunk cost.

Comment: Got bitten by that too. My theory is that it was a bug in .net 1 and hasn't been changed because it'd break existing programs. IMO MS should at least update the intellisense description to indicate that these function have only millisecond precision.

Comment: MS Bug entry: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/653782/timespan-frommilliseconds-incorrect-parsing

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you've found out yourself, it's a documented feature. It's described in the [documentation of TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromseconds.aspx):

> **Parameters**
>
> *value* Type: System.Double
>
> A number of seconds, **accurate to the nearest millisecond**.

The reason for this is probably because a double is not that accurate at all. It is always a good idea to do some rounding when comparing doubles, because it might just be a very tiny bit larger or smaller than you'd expect. That behaviour could actually provide you with some unexpected nanoseconds when you try to put in whole milliseconds. I think that is the reason they chose to round the value to whole milliseconds and discard the smaller digits.

Comment: "Unexpected nanoseconds" sounds like a plausible theory. Still doesn't justify it in _my_ book, but that's beside the point. +1.

Comment: Yes, but milliseconds will probably be enough for most people. People who are smart enough to work with nanoseconds can use `TimeSpan.FromTicks(TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond * YourSecondsDouble)`. ;)

Answer (score 7):

On the rights of a speculation..

1. `TimeSpan.MaxValue.TotalMilliseconds` is equat to 922337203685477. The number that has 15 digits.
2. `double` is precise to 15 digits.
3. `TimeSpan.FromSeconds`, `TimeSpan.FromMinutes` etc. all go through conversion to milliseconds expressed in `double` (then to ticks then to `TimeSpan` which is not interesting now)

So, when you are creating `TimeSpan` that will be close to `TimeSpan.MaxValue` (or `MinValue`) the conversion will be precise to *milliseconds* only.
So the *probable* answer to the question **"why"** is: **to have the *same* precision all the times**.
Further thing to think about is whether the job could have been done better if conversions were done through firstly converting value to ticks expressed in `long`.

Comment: According to the docs, the value *is* converted to ticks first.

Comment: @Golez: Where did you see such doc? [The value parameter is converted to milliseconds, which is converted to ticks, and that number of ticks is used to intialize the new TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromseconds.aspx)

Comment: @Golez: that's OK. We are all mistaken occasionally.

Answer (score 6):

Imagine you're the developer responsible for designing the `TimeSpan` type. You've got all the basic functionality in place; it all seems to be working great. Then one day some beta tester comes along and shows you this code:

```
double x = 100000000000000;
double y = 0.5;
TimeSpan t1 = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(x + y);
TimeSpan t2 = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(x) + TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(y);
Console.WriteLine(t1 == t2);
```

*Why does that output `False`?* the tester asks you. Even though you understand why this happened (the loss of precision in adding together `x` and `y`), you have to admit it does *seem* a bit strange from a client perspective. Then he throws this one at you:

```
x = 10.0;
y = 0.5;
t1 = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(x + y);
t2 = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(x) + TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(y);
Console.WriteLine(t1 == t2);
```

*That one outputs `True`!* The tester is understandably skeptical.

At this point you have a decision to make. Either you can *allow* an arithmetic operation between `TimeSpan` values that have been constructed from `double` values to yield a result **whose precision exceeds the accuracy of the `double` type itself**—e.g., 100000000000000.5 (16 significant figures)—or you can, you know, *not* allow that.

So you decide, you know what, I'll just make it so that any method that uses a `double` to construct a `TimeSpan` will be rounded to the nearest millisecond. That way, it is *explicitly documented* that converting from a `double` to a `TimeSpan` is a lossy operation, absolving me in cases where a client sees weird behavior like this after converting from `double` to `TimeSpan` and hoping for an accurate result.

I'm not necessarily arguing that this is the "right" decision here; clearly, this approach causes some confusion on its own. I'm just saying that a decision needed to be made one way or the other, and this is what was apparently decided.

Comment: You could use this very argument to outlaw doubles altogether... But then, I can imagine the designers paying undue attention to absolute beginners while testing this specific class... Wish we could know for sure how this came into existence :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the explanation is there: [TimeSpan structure incorrectly handles values close to min and max value](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/542235/timespan-structure-incorrectly-handles-values-close-to-min-and-max-value)

And it looks like it's not going to change any time soon :-)

Answer (score 0):

FromSeconds uses private method Interval

```
public static TimeSpan FromSeconds(double value)
{
    return Interval(value, 0x3e8);
}
```

*0x3e8 == 1000*

Interval method multiplay value on that const and then cast to long (see last row):

```
private static TimeSpan Interval(double value, int scale)
{
    if (double.IsNaN(value))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Arg_CannotBeNaN"));
    }
    double num = value * scale; // Multiply!!!!
    double num2 = num + ((value >= 0.0) ? 0.5 : -0.5);
    if ((num2 > 922337203685477) || (num2 < -922337203685477))
    {
        throw new OverflowException(Environment.GetResourceString("Overflow_TimeSpanTooLong"));
    }
    return new TimeSpan(((long) num2) * 0x2710L); // Cast to long!!!
}
```

As result we have precision with 3 (x1000) signs.
*Use reflector to investigate*

Comment: I did of course look. Reflector can always answer the _how_, but not the _why_. Did this help you find out why the cast to long occurs **before** the multiplication? I would consider that a bug had it not been documented. Perhaps it was still a bug that was easier to document than to fix. Bottom line is, this code doesn't answer the "why" question.

Comment: @romkyns "A bug is easier to document than to fix!" I think you just found Microsoft new slogan! ;-)

Comment: @Nicolas: As a separate phrase this sounds amusing. But I don't think that we are having an _unexpected_ bug here. This design might be intentional.

Comment: This answer doesn’t address the question at all.