# Polymorphic method runs twice when called only once

Tags: c#, polymorphism

This is based on another SO question about polymophism which I liked very much.  So I played around with it and modified it to understand it. But then it rattled my understanding of ploymorphism.

I created an interface inside of a class, created a class "A," and implemented the interface method.  I also created another class "B" that extends "A." And another class "C" that extends "B."

When you run it, the output is:

`BA-> AEP`

Notice that `BA->` part comes from `B : A` class while `AEP` is the default param from different method in `A : E`

How is it that two methods are called when I'm doing

```
`A instance = new C();
Console.WriteLine(instance.GetName());`
```

Why?

```
    class Program
{
    interface E
    {
        string GetName(string s);

    }

    public class A : E
    {

        public virtual string GetName(string s="AEP")
        {
            return s;
        }
    }

    public class B : A
    {
        public override string GetName(string s="BAP")
        {
            return "BA-> " + s;
        }
    }

    public class C : B
    {
        public new string GetName()
        {
            return "CB->";
        }
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        A instance = new C();
        Console.WriteLine(instance.GetName());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `return s` to `return s + "bla"` and you'll see it's just the default params

Comment: This is essentially duplicate of 2 questions - one [C# optional parameters on overridden methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8909811/c-sharp-optional-parameters-on-overridden-methods) covers why "AEP" is shown and [C# keyword usage virtual+override vs. new](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159978/c-sharp-keyword-usage-virtualoverride-vs-new) which explains why `C.GetName` is not called at all (and hence "BA->" part of output). Please comment if these links are not enough to clarify the issue.

Comment: @Zuzlx Because you never use `B` in your `Main`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method is not called twice. What you're seeing is that the overridden version from `B` is called, because the run-time instance is `C`. However, because the static type is `A` you're using the default argument value for the method as defined by `A`. Default arguments are a compile time feature inserted at the call site, so it doesn't take the value of the overridden method into account.

Comment: Thanks for that.  Good to know otherwise there would be some interesting bugs.

Answer (score 0):

You are using default parameters here, which is pure syntax sugar and resolved at compile time based on class methods you are using.

```
    A instance = new C();
    Console.WriteLine(instance.GetName());
```

As there's no `GetName()` method without parameters, compiler uses default parameter value and compiles it using declaration in class `A` (variable as it is known at compile time) as `GetName("AEP")`.