# Parallel.ForEach produces inaccurate output

Tags: c#-4.0, parallel-processing

I have got a scenario where I have to run nested foreach's to create a list. The pseudo code of what I do is below

```
foreach(var x in list)           (ForEach1)
   get m // List<string>
   foreach(var k in m)           (ForEach2)
     get t // List<string>
        foreach(var o in t)      (ForEach3)
          // Do some work. and add output to a list
          // which is defined before first for each
```

However, because I retrieve data from an external system(from Perforce by running Perforce commands) in Foreach2 and Foreach3, this piece of code runs really slow and I do need to speed this up.

I tried to use  Parallel.ForEach to run ForEach1 or ForEach2 in parallel. In my tests, it improved the performance significantly, but produced inaccurate result.

- If I run this code with foreach statements, the list I produce has 625 items(which is right)
- If I use Parallel.ForEach for ForEach1, I get 325 added to the list which is well below than I expect.
- and Finally if I use Parallel.ForEach for ForEach2, I get 605 items added to list, still 20 missing.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, or what I am missing. what are the things needing to be considered when using Parallel foreach or for?

Could anyone help me to sort out please? any other suggestion to improve performance would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: This might be of some help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13142099/making-the-most-of-the-net-task-parallel-library

Comment: Have you tried using parallel version for ForEach3?

Comment: Sounds like a race condition of sorts. The collection which you are adding to for your final results, is it a thread-safe collection (e.g. ConcurrentBag<T>)?

Comment: @Taner what is ForEach3?

Comment: @flipchart it was not, but it is now, but did not change anything, I am afraid.

Comment: @AnarchistGeek I mean did you try to change third ForEach into Parallel.ForEach. You wrote (ForEach3) next to it.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what your 'get' operations are, but it also could be an issue with closures.
You can search the net for it.
For example [The foreach identifier and closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512166/c-sharp-the-foreach-identifier-and-closures) and http://www.codethinked.com/c-closures-explained

Comment: That's probably it. An example of how to fix would be good. For example, rather than `get t; foreach (var o in t)`, write `get t; var t_copy = t; foreach (var o in t_copy)`