# odd variable scope in switch statement

Tags: c#, c++, scope, switch-statement

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/241134/1471381) reminded me of an old unanswered question in my mind about switch:

```
    int personType = 1;
    switch (personType)
    {
        case 1:
            Employee emp = new Employee();
            emp.ExperienceInfo();
            break;
        case 2:
            Employee emp = new Employee(); 
            //Error: A local variable named 'emp' is already defined in this scope
            emp.ManagementInfo();
            break;
        case 3:
            Student st = new Student();
            st.EducationInfo();
            break;
        default:
            MessageBox.Show("Not valid ...");
    }
```

why is emp recognized in 'case 2'? in C++ (if I am not wrong) we could use multiple cases together, but in C# that is impossible and we should close `case 1` with break so the following code seems right in C++ and wrong in C#:

```
case 1:
case 2:
   SomeMethodUsedByBothStates();
```

When we can not have such behaviour so why should we be able to declare emp in `case 1` and see it in `case 2`? If never two cases happen together so why should the object be seen in both?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Cases do not create scope in c++ or in c#. All of those variables declared inside a case are in the same scope, that of the switch statement. You need to use braces if you want those variables to be local to some specific case:

```
switch (personType)
{
    case 1: {
        Employee emp = new Employee();
        emp.ExperienceInfo();
        break;
    }
    case 2: {
        Employee emp = new Employee(); 
        // No longer an error; now 'emp' is local to this case.
        emp.ManagementInfo();
        break;
    }
    case 3: {
        Student st = new Student();
        st.EducationInfo();
        break;
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The second code you showed is perfectly fine in C#, assuming case 2 had a `break` or `return`:

```
case 1:
    // no code here...
case 2:
    SomeMethodUsedByBothStates();
    break;
```

Empty cases are allowed to fall through.
What is *not* allowed is to have code in a case-branch that falls through. So, the following would be invalid:

```
case 1:
    SomeMethodUsedOnlyByCase1();
    // no break here...
case 2:
    SomeMethodUsedByBothStates();
    break;
```

---

The question about the scope is a different one.
Basically, the scope is the switch statement itself, not a case-branch.

To make your example compile, simply give the case-branches scopes of their own by adding curly braces:

```
int personType = 1;
switch (personType)
{
    case 1:
    {
        Employee emp = new Employee();
        emp.ExperienceInfo();
        break;
    }
    case 2:
    {
        Employee emp = new Employee(); 
        emp.ManagementInfo();
        break;
    }
    case 3:
    {
        Student st = new Student();
        st.EducationInfo();
        break;
    }
    default:
        MessageBox.Show("Not valid ...");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you declare variables inside a case, use braces to spesification.

```
int personType = 1;
switch (personType)
{
    case 1: 
   {
     ///
     break;
   }
    case 2: 
   {
     ///
     break;
    }
    case 3: 
   {
        ///
        break;
   }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The scope is not odd at all. The scope of a local variable is from the point where it's defined to the end of the block in which it's defined. So the various `emp` variables are each in scope until the end of the block that starts with the `{` after the `switch` statement and ends at the corresponding `}`. There's nothing special about `case` labels; they don't change the scope of variables.