# What is the advantage of Path.TryJoin over Path.Combine in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, path, .net-core

I just started using .NET Core 2.1, and found the [`Path.TryJoin`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.tryjoin?view=netcore-2.1) and [`Path.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.join?view=netcore-2.1) method. There is no documentation on the method.

I ran some unit tests calling the method, and it did nothing different than [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=netcore-2.1).

Is there any advantage to this other than utilizing the new C# [`Span<T>`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2018/03/25/c-7-series-part-10-spant-and-universal-memory-management/) data type to minimize string manipulation execution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can find the rationale behind the `Path.Join` being introduced [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/25536). IMHO it seems to be trading simplicity for performance and some minor fixes, also couldn't find any indication that Join creates cross-platform valid paths with the correct separators like `Path.Combine` does but by all accounts is should.

To elaborate on the discussion, the main quirk that `Path.Join` resolves is the last rooted argument which a lot of people don't expect to work the way it does (which seamed minor but clearly is not), as can be seen in the examples here on the [the worst gotcha in C# or .NET page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1141114/3073551).

The general idea from the discussion is to slowly deprecate `Combine` in favor of `Join`.

Also note string overloads have been added for the `Path.Join` with this [PR](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/18458)

Comment: If you could add some of the discussion about how the `Span<char>` is coming from some devices to your answer, I'll accept it. I don't want this to stay as link-only in case the URL changes.