# C# - are all Enum constants?

Tags: .net, enums

Are all Enum enumerations constants? Do they get **converted to their value at compile-time**, or at run-time?

Comment: Can't imagine why anyone would vote down this question.

Comment: Maybe because (s)he thought that anyone could answer this question with Google and should try that first. I personally haven't yet come to a conclusion where to draw the line, but IMHO there should be a line.

Comment: Google's powered by sites like this so easy questions like this are fine by me. I'd much prefer these to all the silly poll questions.

Comment: Sure, Google will index this answer too. But sometimes I wish there was a little less I'm-too-lazy-to-Google-myself noise in all the newsgroups, which would leave us more time to deal with the interesting questions. Note: I'm not saying that this question is noise, but others might have thought so.

Comment: True--I can't argue with you there.

Comment: Andreas, the key takeaway is everybody's "line" is drawn in a different position.

Comment: I've been bitten by this! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194484/whats-the-strangest-corner-case-youve-seen-in-c-or-net/311831#311831

Comment: Sometimes questions like this can bring out interesting comments that are tangental to the straightforward main question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

They are constant. Yes, compile time.

Reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx

From the intro:

> The enum keyword is used to declare
>   an enumeration, a distinct type that
>   consists of a set of **named constants**
>   called the enumerator list.

Under "Robust Programming":

> Just as with any constant, all
>   references to the individual values of
>   an enum are **converted to numeric
>   literals at compile time**. This can
>   create potential versioning issues as
>   described in Constants (C# Programming
>   Guide).

Answer (score 7):

Enum values are constants, they cannot change.

Their values are fixed at compile time.