# What is the reason for specifying an Enum as uint?

Tags: c#

I came across some Enumerators that inherited `uint`.  I couldn't figure out why anyone would do this.

Example:

```
Enum myEnum : uint
{
   ...
}
```

Any advantage or specific reason someone would do this?  Why not just leave it as defaultint?

Comment: Feb 2021: Microsoft's documentation (Nov 2019) states that Enums should be Int32.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1028

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One reason I can think of is that range checking is easier.  Given that most enumerations start at 0, you'd only have to check the upper bound.

Answer (score 31):

if the enumeration values are greater than 2,147,483,647 and non-negative.

Comment: Why the down vote?  I thought that was a valid reason to do this?

Comment: What about those values that only should not be negative?

Comment: Sorry, having a hard time figuring out what you mean, can you restate the question?

Comment: I didn't downvote it, but there's only one case I can imagine where this would apply... When you are using a flags enum that has to represent exactly 32 distinct booleans... Then it might make sense to use an uint to avoid switching to a long... But one more to 33, and you would need a long anyway.

Comment: I could agree with that in most circumstances, but when working with a 3rd party POS system, they had over 2200 flags stored in a single file in 32 bit chunks for faster indexing.  Thus uint is used to store the values.

Comment: @Tom,  in your scenario, did all 2200 flags potentially need to be represented in a single enum in application code logic?

Comment: yes, unfortunately, as there are a lot of "paired" flag combinations that don't exist in the same file space, its a huge mess to be honest.

Comment: I meant, that not only values greater than and non-negative would require a uint, but also values that should be non-negative.

Answer (score 9):

I'd guess it's been done to allow it to be automatically cast to a uint (in C, enums were treated as ints by the type system).  Quite possibly to allow bitwise ORing of flag values for the enum.  see http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t286596-enums-in-c-and-c.html

Answer (score 9):

It is convenient and absolutely necessary in some cases when working with COM Interop / P/Invoke from .NET. For example, you'll certainly find some at [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net) defined this way. In some cases it just maps closer to the underlying API definition, but isn't necessary, but in some cases the underlying API might use some of those high bits for flags and it will be required to be UINT.
Outside of Interop, you could use some very high bits as flags too just in plain C#/VB.NET and that might also require uint.

Answer (score 4):

I'm converting some messaging code originally written in C into C#.

Some fields in the C code have a limited set of possible values defined as an associated group of #defines.  In other words an enumeration.

When converting some of these enumerations, some values are too large for an integer e.g.

#define NONE 0x00000000

#define VAL1 0x00000001

...

#define VALX 0x80000000

Here, VALX won't be acceptable to a default enum in C#, so the enum has to be cast as a *uint*, which is also the type of the storing variable in the record structure.

Answer (score 1):

The example I'm talking about is in the code here:
http://www.codeplex.com/FacebookNET

Take a look at the class FacebookResponseStatus.cs

I could email the author but I thought not to bother and just see what people think in the general community based on other experiences.

I am not going to be using this framework on CodePlex, but was reviewing it to see how others were implementing Facebook into .NET.  I just thought it was interesting and wanted to know why the : uint for the Enums there.

Answer (score 1):

looks like they are doing it purely for this one error, which means there are probably more errors not implemented in that class.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// There was an HTTP error in issuing the request.
    /// </summary>
    HttpError = 0xFFFF0000
```

Answer (score 1):

I know of another reason, 'cos a colleague did it here.

To avoid the problem explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194484/whats-the-strangest-corner-case-youve-seen-in-c-or-net/311831#311831) (item 2), when generating a list of enums, he give it a unique value based on the string (I can't remember exactly how now, it can't be the hashcode 'cos that's not unique).

The only problem was that the numbers come out a bit big, so he made the enum a uint.

Answer (score 0):

This is so you can use bitwise math to store multiple items into one variable.

for example

```
[Flags]
    public enum SodaTypes: uint
    {
        None = 0b_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000,
        PepsiNormal = 0b_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0001,
        DietPepsi = 0b_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0010,
        Coke = 0b_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0100,
        DietCoke = 0b_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_1000,
        .
        .
        .
        .
        Fanta = 0b_1000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000
    }
```

So once you can basically store multiple options like so:

SodasLiked = SodaTypes.Pepsi | SodaTypes.Fanta | SodaTypes.DietCoke;

and when you print this you will get:

```
Console.WriteLine(SodasLiked);
```

Output:

```
Pepsi, DietCoke,Fanta
```