# Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory has been corrupted

Tags: winforms, user-controls

I created a Winforms AutoComplete combobox control inheriting from ComboBox with the following method:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnKeyPress(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnKeyPress(e)
        Dim text As String = Me.Text
        If Char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) Then
            text = text + e.KeyChar
        End If
        If (text.Length = AutoCompleteSearchChars And Char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar)) Then
            SetAutoCompleteMethod.Invoke(text)
            Me.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems
            Me.Text = text
            Me.SelectionStart = text.Length
            Me.SelectionLength = 0
            If Me.Items.Count > 0 Then
                Me.SelectedIndex = 0
            End If
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub
```

The "SetAutoCompleteMethod" is a delegate pointing to a method that populates the
combobox items based on using the current text in the combo box as the prefix for a
wildcard search.  This provides similar functionality to the ajax autocomplete combobox.

This all works fine the first time it is called, but the second time it is called I get the "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory has been corrupted" error.  The error appears after all the code to update the combobox is completed.  I get the following stack trace:

> at
>   System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG&
>   msg)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.
>   UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32
>   dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32
>   pvLoopData)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)
>   at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)
>   at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(ApplicationContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[]
>   commandLine)    at
>   ApplicationShell.My.MyApplication.Main(String[]
>   Args) in
>   17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line
>   81    at
>   System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly
>   assembly, String[] args)    at
>   System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String
>   assemblyFile, Evidence
>   assemblySecurity, String[] args)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>   at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object
>   state)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback
>   callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Is Anyone able to point me in the right direction to solve this?

Comment: I believe this has something to do with the datasource. I set the datasource for the combo box to 'nothing' before loading new items and the error happens less frequently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I've gotten that error, it turned out to really be an issue with dereferencing a null pointer, but it made the method call anyway and didn't crash until it tried to access one of the member variables.  I haven't really worked with VB since before the days of .Net, but your stack trace suggests it died in a native call somewhere.  If that's the case, you might be running into the same issue in which case I'd recommend you double check those pointers, not just where it crashes, but a couple levels up too.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an object to the items collection whose ToString() method returns nothing is an easy way to get this. There are probably other ways to reach the same behavior.

Proceed to diagnosis it as if it were a NullReferenceException.

See [What's the strangest corner case you've seen in C# or .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194484/whats-the-strangest-corner-case-youve-seen-in-c-or-net#194685) for another case.