# How to resolve ambiguous ZIP call between Enumerable and MoreLINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ambiguous-call, morelinq

I've ran into problem with extension method resolution. LINQ and MoreLINQ contain `zip` method, it was present in .NET since **4.0** version and was always in [MoreLINQ](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) library. But you can't use one of the implementation with nice-old extension method syntax. So this code won't compile

```
using MoreLinq;
using System.Linq;


var students = new [] { "Mark", "Bob", "David" };
var colors = new [] { "Pink", "Red", "Blue" };

students.Zip(colors, (s, c) => s + c );
```

Error:

```
The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 
'MoreLinq.MoreEnumerable.Zip<string,string,string>
(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>, 
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>, System.Func<string,string,string>)' and 
'System.Linq.Enumerable.Zip<string,string,string>
(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>, 
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>, System.Func<string,string,string>)'
```

I've found good resolution for `Concat` method on `string` for MoreLINQ made by Jon Skeet  at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610870/when-do-extension-methods-break/610908#610908), but I'm not aware of good resolution for `zip` method.

**NOTE:** You can always use static method call syntax and it all works fine with

```
MoreEnumerable.Zip(students, colors, (s, c) => s + c )
```

but misses the point of extension syntax sugar a little bit. If you have lots of data transformation with LINQ and MoreLINQ calls - you don't want to use static method call in the middle.

Are there any better ways to resolve this ambiguity?

Comment: Isn't there a 4.0-friendly version of MoreLINQ? (ie one that drops MoreLINQ's own `Zip` function)

Comment: ... or just make one yourself, it's open source :)

Comment: @AakashM no there isn't. You can see their issue regarding `zip` and .NET 4.0 here http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/issues/detail?id=60 and NoConflict resolution here https://gist.github.com/2869531

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A way to make it compile would be:

```
var students = new[] { "Mark", "Bob", "David", "test" }.AsQueryable();
var colors = new[] { "Pink", "Red", "Blue" };

students
    .Zip(colors, (s, c) => s + c)
    .Dump();
```

The `students` object has to be converted to an `IQueryable` object.

Comment: What's all the `dynamic` for? And what about `AsQueryable()`?

Comment: No need for `dynamic` here.

Comment: You can remove that parenthesis in array declaration and make it `new [] { "..." }.AsQueryable();` and call it only in the first array of `students`

Answer (score 5):

You can create a wrapper class with the same method, but diffrent name. It's a bit dirty, but if you really like to have extension syntax, that is the only way.

```
public static class MoreLinqWrapper
{
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> MlZip<TFirst, TSecond, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TFirst> first, IEnumerable<TSecond> second, Func<TFirst, TSecond, TResult> resultSelector)
    {
        return MoreLinq.Zip(first, second, resultSelector);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I also thought about it and wrote to Dennis answer. but I don't know if it is a better approach

Comment: It's ok until he has single `MoreLinq` call or he will use this fake method instead of `Zip`. The 1st case is not applicable - see the question text, the second case - well, I don't envy the person, who will have to support this code. I think, it will be hard to explain after year or two, why here's the call to `MlZip` (and what it is) instead of `Zip`.

Comment: Dennis, usually I solve this problem by "Goto definition", and inside you'll immediately see the answer. Of course this is not a good solution. But comparing to having to replace lots of call to static syntax, I would choose this one.

Comment: Ilya, here you should choose the least of two evils. I would make decision based on number of actual code lines I would have to change. I the number of usages is small, I would use static class syntax.
Also, did you consider to just stop using MoreLinq? I was evaluating it, and found it not so good, but rather dirting the namespace. I only used 1-2 functions from it. And just copied them to my own extensions class.

Comment: Ilya, as I said, I found only a couple of functions helpful, and all others were simply contaminating namespace. So I moved those 2-3 funcs to my own class and dereferenced MoreLinq.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this the other day and I simply called the MoreLinq method directly.

```
MoreLinq.MoreEnumerable.Zip(students, colors, (s, c) => s + c);
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your morelinq, and from now

- Use `Zip` for .NET 4.0 Zip
- Use `ZipShortest` for MoreLinq Zip

Problem is fixed in [88c573f7](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/commit/88c573f7bbcd15d0cd09f22e9b73b62dce9b66ed)

Comment: As of Nov 2014 (version 1.1) MoreLinq still contains Zip; i.e. it appears this patch was not used, and the problem still happens.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the static method call syntax is the only way here.

Comment: Well, another way I can think of is to clone signature and create separate method with `Zipp` name, for example, that will call `MoreEnumerable.Zip`. But I don't think it's a better approach