# Method 'Generate' in type xxx does not have an implementation - S#arp - UPDATED

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, castle-windsor, s#arp-architecture, typeloadexception

I've been using S#arp and have updated the `Generate` method in `AutoPersistenceModelGenerator` to work with Fluent NHibernate 1.1. I also changed its assembly name from MyProject.Data to MyProject.Infrastructure and I'm not sure which has caused the problem:

```
    public AutoPersistenceModel Generate()
    {
        return AutoMap.Assemblies(new myProjectMappingConfiguration(),
                                  typeof (MyClass).Assembly)
            .Conventions.Setup(GetConventions())
            .IgnoreBase<Entity>()
            .IgnoreBase(typeof (EntityWithTypedId<>))
            .UseOverridesFromAssemblyOf<AutoPersistenceModelGenerator>();
    }
```

At the point that Castle Windsor registers the assembly containing the above method...

```
        container.Register(
            AllTypes.Pick()
            .FromAssemblyNamed("MyProject.Infrastructure")
            .WithService.FirstNonGenericCoreInterface("MyProject.Core"));
```

...it throws this exception:

> Method 'Generate' in type 'MyProject.Infrastructure.NHibernateMaps.AutoPersistenceModelGenerator' from assembly 'MyProject.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.

I've completely cleaned the project and rebuilt it but the error keeps happening.

I don't know if this makes a difference but the above method is actually called directly in Global.asax:

```
    private void InitializeNHibernateSession()
    {
        var cfg = NHibernateSession.Init(
            webSessionStorage,
            new string[] { Server.MapPath("~/bin/MyProject.Infrastructure.dll") },
            new AutoPersistenceModelGenerator().Generate(),
            Server.MapPath("~/NHibernate.config"));
     }
```

I've tried removing the IOC registration but the same error is then thrown on this method:

```
    public void Initialize(Action initMethod)
    {
        if (!this.NHibernateSessionIsLoaded)
        {
            lock (syncLock)
            {
                if (!this.NHibernateSessionIsLoaded)
                {
                    initMethod();
                    this.NHibernateSessionIsLoaded = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**

**I recreated my project and unwent the same process again - the error appears to happen when I update Fluent NHibernate from 1.0 to 1.1. Any ideas why?**

Comment: Are you sure you're not loading an older version of the assembly -- possibly from the GAC?  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948785/typeloadexception-says-no-implementation-but-it-is-implemented

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this was caused by part of the S#arp architecture assemblies referencing the old Fluent NHibernate version.

I updated the S#arp assemblies to 1.6 (which now uses FNH 1.1) and it now works.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same issue but am not ready to update my sharparch version, also I am using the 2.0.0.0 version of fluentnhibernate.  You can work around this by using an assembly binding redirect in your app.config or web.config.  Like this:

```
    <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="FluentNhibernate" publicKeyToken="8aa435e3cb308880" culture="neutral"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-65535.65535.65535.65535" newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```