# Castle Keeps giving me a System.TypeLoadException: Method 'myMethod' does not have implementation?

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, ioc-container

```cs
System.TypeInitializationException:
 The type initializer for 'XXX' threw an exception.

System.TypeLoadException:
 Method 'GetDocuments' in type 'YYY' from assembly 'ZZZ,
  Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral PublicKeyToken=null'
  does not have an implementation..
```

I am getting the above error when trying to resolve an object with Castle Windsor. After some Googling it seems that others have had this problem due to assembly version mismatches. I don't believe this can be my problem since the assembly containing 'myMethod' is referenced in  one project. I have create another test project that attempts to resolve the object.

Can someone tell me what I'm missing here?

This is the component registration that fails:

```cs
private static void Register_IContentDirectory()
    {
        _container.Register(
            Component.For<IContentDirectory>()
                .ImplementedBy<DocumentumContentDirectory>()
                .ServiceOverrides(
                    ServiceOverride.ForKey("documentManagementServiceProvider").Eq(
                        "document.management.service.provider")
                ));
    }
```

UPDATE:

I have voted to close this Q. My problem is a dependency on another assembly. Not related to castle.

Comment: have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948785/typeloadexception-says-no-implementation-but-it-is-implemented ?

Comment: you can answer yourself and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Nick:

> My problem is a dependency on another assembly. Not related to castle.