# Reflection in c# Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information

Tags: c#, reflection

Below code gives me LoaderExceptions. I am not sure why and how i could do it differently.

```
  Type typDatabaseImplClass2 = CoreDatabaseImplAssembly.GetType("Binit.Core.Database.Implementation.DbDoubleDimensionImpl");
```

Full Exception Details

```
"Method 'PassObjectToCPP' in type 'Binit.Core.Database.Implementation.DbDoubleUnitsImpl' from assembly 'Binit.Core.Database.Implementation, Version=1.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=17c64733a9775004' does not have an implementation.":"Binit.Core.Database.Implementation.DbDoubleUnitsImpl"}    System.Exception {System.TypeLoadException}
```

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/948785/1997232)?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you class 'DbDoubleDimensionImpl' use or call a method 'PassObjectToCPP' that doesn't exist in the current executing context.