# C# library which references older version of nuget dependency causes assembly reflection to fail

Tags: c#, .net, swashbuckle

One of the nuget dependencies in my project ([Swashbuckle](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle)) requires a version of the `System.Web.Http` library (4.0.0.0) that is older than the version required by the rest of the project (5.2.3.0).

Swashbuckle requires that I write a class implementing a certain interface:

```
public class OperationFilter : Swashbuckle.Swagger.IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(Swashbuckle.Swagger.Operation operation, Swashbuckle.Swagger.SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, System.Web.Http.Description.ApiDescription apiDescription)
    {

    }
}
```

The important part above is the `apiDescription` parameter of `Apply`.

When building the project normally, the above compiles and runs fine. However, when I reflect over the running assembly using `assembly.GetTypes()`,

```
var asm = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var types = asm.GetTypes()
```

a `ReflectionTypeLoadException` is thrown, with the following loader exception details:

```
Method 'Apply' in type 'OperationFilter' from assembly 'MyAssembly, 
Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an 
implementation.
```

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948785/typeloadexception-says-no-implementation-but-it-is-implemented) references the above exception, but none of the solutions posed seem to work.
I tried to solve the issue by adding a bindingRedirect to Web.config:

```
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
```

However, that didn't seem to do anything.

How can I get this type to load properly?

EDIT: I've created [a minimal reproduction of the issue](https://github.com/JustASquid/TestSwaggerAssemblyIssue). A build task in `BuildTask.targets` loads the project assembly and then tries to load all the types. The errors are thrown and displayed.

Comment: Do you have a minimal project reproducing your issue? I would like to try it with my version of Swashbuckle: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swagger-Net/

Comment: @HelderSepu I just added a repro, thanks!

Comment: That project is not a WebApi...

Comment: I sent you a PullRequest on GitHub: https://github.com/JustASquid/TestSwaggerAssemblyIssue/pull/1

Comment: @HelderSepu So this is a fork of swashbuckle? Why doesn't swashbuckle itself have the lastest versions?

Comment: I wish I could answer that question, I tried to update it but the owner disagreed. _  You can ask the owner yourself: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/pull/1062

Comment: Did you try Swagger-Net? _ I'm always looking for feedback (good and bad)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on my comments...

I just tested the sample project and this issue can be fixed by using [Swagger-Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swagger-Net/).

That is my fork of Swashbuckle, I've upgraded all dependencies to the latest and using also latest of the Swagger-UI (3.x), it is quite a drastic change from the old one, let me know how you like it.

Comment: I'm not sure I want to move to a library that is not as heavily supported/used as Swashbuckle. Is there a reason Swagger-Net isn't a just a PR to swashbuckle?

Comment: What do you mean by not heavily supported? I personally do the support, I fix bugs and add features quite often, just look at the release frequency on NuGet