# Nservicebus unity Endpoint failed to start

Tags: c#, unity-container, nservicebus

Using .NET 4.5.2, Visual studio 2017, C# 7.1, Unity, NServiceBus 6.

I receive the following error:
[image: Exception error]

My application is a console app, here's some of the Program.cs code:

```
private static async Task ConfigureUnity()
    {
        IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

        var endpointConfiguration = new EndpointConfiguration("NSB.ChannelAdvisorService");
        var transport = endpointConfiguration.UseTransport<LearningTransport>();
        endpointConfiguration.AssemblyScanner().ExcludeAssemblies("netstandard");

        endpointConfiguration.UseContainer<UnityBuilder>(
            customizations =>
            {
                customizations.UseExistingContainer(container);
            });

        var endpointInstance = Endpoint.Start(endpointConfiguration).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        //register
        container.RegisterType(typeof(IGenericHttpRequestRepository<>), typeof(GenericHttpRequestRepository<>), new TransientLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<IOrderRepository, OrderRepository>();
        container.RegisterType<IShipmentRepository, ShipmentRepository>();
        container.RegisterType<IOrderProcessService, OrderProcessService>();
        container.RegisterType<IShipmentService, ShipmentService>();
        container.RegisterInstance(endpointConfiguration);

        //resolve 
        var orderProcessService = container.Resolve<IOrderProcessService>();
        var shipmentService = container.Resolve<IShipmentService>();
 .....
```

As you can see I'm using Unity and NServiceBus, this is to register DI and also use it withing NServicebus so i can DI it into my service to send a command.

The service trys to DI "IEndpointInstance"

```
public class OrderProcessService : IOrderProcessService
{
    private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    private readonly IEndpointInstance _endpoint;

    public OrderProcessService(IEndpointInstance endpoint)
    {
        _endpoint = endpoint;
    }

    public async Task PostNewOrderBatch()
    {
        var list = _orderRepository.GetBatchedOrders();

        foreach(var item in list)// parallel this?
        {
            await _endpoint.Send(item.ToObject<ProcessBatchOrdersCommand>()).ConfigureAwait(false);

    _orderRepository.DeleteFile(item.Property("FilePath").Value.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

I get the feeling it could be an issue about the order of things, I don't think I've missed anything out as far as i can tell in some examples?

Comment: Hope this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948785/typeloadexception-says-no-implementation-but-it-is-implemented

Comment: wierd, i just got the sample solution from nservicebus unity, tried it on my machine and got the same error.  Also tried it on a different machine, same error...

Comment: This sample? https://docs.particular.net/samples/dependency-injection/unity/?version=unity_8

Comment: no, this one https://github.com/Particular/docs.particular.net/tree/master/samples/dependency-injection/unity/Unity_8  doesnt work on my windows 7 machine

Comment: @lemunk see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47713897/nservicebus-unity-endpoint-failed-to-start#comment82755074_47749666

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In NServiceBus v6 and later the endpoint instance is no longer automatically registered in the container. You need to register the endpoint instance returned from `Endpoint.Start(configuration)` on the existing container.

See https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/dependency-injection/#using-an-existing-instance-endpoint-resolution

Comment: already tried, seems to be an issue with the version of the sample.

Comment: We are using NuGet wild cards in our samples, and it appears that a recent release of Unity broke SemVer, so we raised an issue: https://github.com/unitycontainer/unity/issues/171