# ReflectionTypeLoadException - Method does not have an implementation

Tags: c#, .net

In my solution many Assemblies (Plugins) are loaded via `AssemblyLoadContext` in runtime. Now I'm facing the mentioned issue, if I load a Plugin that uses an Interface, the executing program (in my case a unit-test) already uses / loads.

I sure know this issue of different interface versions ([Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948785/typeloadexception-says-no-implementation-but-it-is-implemented)) but my versions are totally the same. The files even match binary 100%. The only problem seams to be, that it is loaded from a different location. If I force the `PlugInLoadContext` to reload the interface from the Plugin's location, it seams to work (but this isn't possible for some other reasons / pretty unclean).

Any idea what could cause this behavior? Or is it just not possible?

Since its just super hard to describe, if created this minimal repro to download: [Download](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/files/12805199/ReflectionTypeLoadException.zip) / [Github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/93013)

### Setup

We need four projects, all in .NET 7.

First is a shared library called `SharedLib` that defines just a single interface:

```cs
namespace SharedLib;
public interface ISharedInterface { }
```

Then an interface library called `InterfaceLib` referencing the `SharedLib` with this definition:

```cs
using SharedLib;

namespace InterfaceLib;
public interface IInterface
{
    Task Action(ISharedInterface shared);
}
```

Next, a "user-supplied" library, called `ClassLib` that references both projects above:

```cs
using InterfaceLib;
using SharedLib;

namespace ClassLib;
public class Implementation : IInterface
{ 
    public Task Action(ISharedInterface shared) => 
      throw new NotImplementedException(); 
}
// If this class is not contained, you do net get an exception!
public class SharedImplementation : ISharedInterface { }
```

Finally, the main `Program` library, referencing only the `InterfaceLib`. The main code is relatively simple, but note the `IInterface` reference without which the issue doesn't reproduce:

```cs
// If this line is commented out, you do not get an exception!
InterfaceLib.IInterface _;

var pluginPath = Path.GetFullPath(AppContext.BaseDirectory + @"..\\..\\..\\..\\ClassLib\\bin\\Debug\\net7.0\\ClassLib.dll");

var context = new PlugInLoadContext();
context.AddPlugIn(pluginPath);

// Exeption here.
var types = context.PlugIns.SelectMany(suba => suba.GetTypes().ToArray()).ToArray();
```

and the implementation of the `PlugInLoadContext` is:

```cs
public class PlugInLoadContext : AssemblyLoadContext
{
    private readonly List<AssemblyDependencyResolver> _resolvers = new List<AssemblyDependencyResolver>();
    private readonly Dictionary<string, Assembly> _knownPlugIns = new Dictionary<string, Assembly>();

    public IEnumerable<Assembly> PlugIns => _knownPlugIns.Select(a => a.Value);

    public Assembly AddPlugIn(string plugInPath)
    {
        if (_knownPlugIns.TryGetValue(plugInPath, out var assembly)) { return assembly; }

        var result = Load(AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(plugInPath));

        if (result == null)
        {
            _resolvers.Add(new AssemblyDependencyResolver(plugInPath));
            result = LoadFromAssemblyPath(plugInPath);
        }

        _knownPlugIns.Add(plugInPath, result);

        return result;
    }

    protected override Assembly? Load(AssemblyName assemblyName)
    {
        var result = LoadInternal(assemblyName);
        if (result != null) { Console.WriteLine($"{assemblyName.Name} loaded from {result.Location}"); }
        return result;
    }

    protected Assembly? LoadInternal(AssemblyName assemblyName)
    {
        var knownAssembly = Default.Assemblies.FirstOrDefault(a => a.FullName == assemblyName.FullName);
        if (knownAssembly != null) { return knownAssembly; }

        var assemblyPath = _resolvers.Select(r => r.ResolveAssemblyToPath(assemblyName)).Where(p => p != null).FirstOrDefault();
        if (assemblyPath != null) { return LoadFromAssemblyPath(assemblyPath); }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Running this code produces this output:

```
System.Runtime loaded from C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\7.0.11\System.Runtime.dll
SharedLib loaded from <userpath>\ReflectionTypeLoadException\ClassLib\bin\Debug\net7.0\SharedLib.dll
InterfaceLib loaded from <userpath>\ReflectionTypeLoadException\Program\bin\Debug\net7.0\InterfaceLib.dll
Unhandled exception. System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
Method 'Action' in type 'ClassLib.Implementation' from assembly 'ClassLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
   at Program.<>c.<<Main>$>b__0_0(Assembly suba) in <userpath>\ReflectionTypeLoadException\Program\Program.cs:line 17
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectManySingleSelectorIterator`2.ToArray()
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in <userpath>\ReflectionTypeLoadException\Program\Program.cs:line 17
System.TypeLoadException: Method 'Action' in type 'ClassLib.Implementation' from assembly 'ClassLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.
```

Comment: We can't help you without a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

Comment: I'll try my very best, even though it's pretty hard to do / much code. Whats the best way to share it? I need a solution with three projects with some code.

Comment: You can tell us that there are three separate projects and what should go in each one. Try to remove any code that seems irrelevant, as long as the exception still reproduces.

Comment: I've added a minimal repro. Still way to confusing to put the real code here, I'm sorry.

Comment: Can you add a link that doesn't immediatelly download a zip file? I'm sorry to be a negative nancy here, but a lot of people, myself included, are not going to feel fine about downloading a direct zip file with potentially unknown contents.

Comment: Judging by the link the file is probably linked in some GitHub issue. A link to that issue would be fine.

Comment: Added the issue

Comment: not necessairy a solution, but an advise. Keep track of what plugins are already loaded, and skip loading the same thing twice.  Load each plugin into a new assembly context, check if given plugin is already loaded, if yes, unload.

Comment: Thank you for that recommendation! But since I'm in control of all the PlugIns, I can ensure that all use the same shared libs / package versions. It makes no problem at runtime since all files are in a single directory. Just debugging isn't working since the interface is loaded from two locations - but shouldn't it work anyway?