# What is the meaning of NullReferenceException

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

For example, "`System.NullReferenceException` was unhandled", with Message "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

What is the meaning of this exception, and how can it be solved?

Answer (score 14):

It means you've tried to access a member of something that isn't there:

```
string s = null;
int i = s.Length; // boom
```

Just fix the thing that is null. Either make it non-null, or perform a null-test first.

There is also a [corner-case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194484#194671) here related to `Nullable<T>`, generics and the `new` generic constraint - a bit unlikely though (but heck, I hit this issue!).

Answer (score 8):

This is the most common exception in .NET... it just mean that you try to call a member of a variable that is not initialized (null). You need to initialize this variable before you can call its members

Comment: Note that this advice applies to "fields" (instance/static variables) - but not to local variables (definite assignment is applied to local variables; you can't even *attempt* to use an uninitialized local variable).

Answer (score 2):

It means you're referencing something that's `null`, for example:

```
class Test
{

   public object SomeProp
   {
      get;
      set;
   }

}

new Test().SomeProp.ToString()
```

`SomeProp` will be null and should throw a `NullReferenceException`. This is commonly due to code you are calling expecting something to be there that isn't.

Comment: If `o` is a local variable, this won't compile. Unassigned local variables are not `null`.

Comment: You're right. Changed the example.

Answer (score 1):

That means that you have tried to use a method or property of an object, when the variable is not yet initialized:

```
string temp;
int len = temp.Length; // throws NullReferenceException; temp is null

string temp2 = "some string";
int len2 = temp2.Length; // this works well; temp is a string
```

Comment: For local variables (as per the example shown), it *is* initialized (otherwise it won't compile). Simply: it is initialized to null.

Comment: if 'temp' is a local variable it will _not_ compile. If it's a field it will be null.

Answer (score 1):

The code below will show you the exception, and a clue.

```
string s = null;
s = s.ToUpper();
```

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in your code, you have an object reference, and it's not set to an instance of an object :)

Somewhere you've used an object without calling it's constructor.

what you should do:

```
MyClass c = new MyClass();
```

what you've done:

```
MyClass c;
c.Blah();
```

Comment: Which won't compile... (definite assignment)

Comment: You're right, and they won't have my implementation of MyClass either.

Let's do

            Random r = null;
            r.Next();

instead then.