# What use is this code?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, interface

I can't figure out the use for [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194484/whats-the-strangest-corner-case-youve-seen-in-c-or-net/1332344#1332344). Of what use is this pattern?

[code repeated here for posterity]

```
public class Turtle<T> where T : Turtle<T>
{
}
```

Comment: Its turtles all the way down...

Comment: Wha!? I've gotta be missing something...

Comment: Needs more turtles, if you ask me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This pattern essentially allows you to refer to a concrete subclass within the parent class.
For example:

```
public abstract class Turtle<T> where T : Turtle<T>
{
    public abstract T Procreate();
}

public class SeaTurtle : Turtle<SeaTurtle>
{
    public override SeaTurtle Procreate()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Versus:

```
public abstract class Turtle
{
    public abstract Turtle Procreate();
}

public class SnappingTurtle : Turtle
{
    public override Turtle Procreate()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

In the former, it's specified that a `SeaTurtle`'s baby will be a `SeaTurtle`.

Comment: Do you think, this kind of thing would not be required, if there is support for contra variance?

Comment: It's got more uses. It may implement interfaces for the subclass. Like, in Java, `java.lang.Enum` uses the pattern to implement `java.lang.Comparable` for the subclass. I'm sure C# has something similar.

Comment: There are certainly other uses, but they all involve the parent class needing to use the type of its subclass. Regarding implementation of interfaces, you have two choices: implement the interface for T or Turtle<T>. IComparable<T> would only let you compare items of the same subclass, where IComparable<Turtle<T>> would let you compare any Turtle. And since .NET 4.0's IComparable<T> will be contravariant in T, you will be able to use an IComparable<Turtle<T>> as an IComparable<T> because T : Turtle<T>.

Answer (score -1):

There is no use that I can see.  Basically, it's the same as

```
public class Turtle
{
}
```

Comment: It's not the same because in the code given, `Turtle` cannot be instantiated.

Comment: Yes it can... see Marc Gravell's comment here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194484/whats-the-strangest-corner-case-youve-seen-in-c-or-net/1332344#1332344

Comment: @Levesque, And see RCIX's comment following.

Comment: My question is where does it have any use?

Comment: Something just occured to me. You can subclass `Turtle` and instantiate that but you can't instantiate a copy of `Turtle` itself.

Comment: @RCIX, But can you subclass Turtle?  Doesn't it require a generic parameter?  With generics, you are creating a type, not a "copy" or instance.

Comment: @strager : Yes, you can. Look at Marc's comment, he gives an example.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the comments to that answer.  Sorry!