# How can I get a NullReferenceException in this code sample?

Tags: c#, .net

```
??? o = new ???();

Console.WriteLine("ToString() -> " + o.ToString() ); //<--- Prints 'ToString() -> '
Console.WriteLine("GetType() -> " + o.GetType()); //<--- NullReferenceException
```

**Output:**

```
ToString() -> 

Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set 
to an instance of an object.
at System.Object.GetType()
at Program.Main(String[] args)
```

#### Question

What is the type `???` and why does `o.ToString()` return `string.Empty` and `o.GetType()` throws a `NullReferenceException`?

> **Note**: `GetType()` is not redefined in the `???` type.

Comment: If the type is `Nullable<T>`, this will happen since `GetType` is not `virtual` and the object will have to be boxed in order to call `Object.GetType` in the base class, and a nullable type will box to null, and a method call on null will cause a NullReferenceException. This is not a real question--voted to close.

Comment: Completely disagree with the close. The question is clear - what type would give a NullReferenceException. Just because the OP implies they know the answer doesn't make this "not a real question". It's some C# trivia that others can learn from. HOwever, it is now answered so reopening seems futile.

Comment: I think this is a real question.

Comment: There are two different examples on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194484/whats-the-strangest-corner-case-youve-seen-in-c-or-net/194671#194671

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any `Nullable<T>`.

Check [Gravell's example to strange corner cases in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194484/whats-the-strangest-corner-case-youve-seen-in-c-or-net/194671#194671)

Comment: An even more interesting example is the `MyFunnyType` on the same answer.

Comment: A Nullable<T> doesn't produce the stack trace above.  The stack trace line 'at System.Object.GetType()' implies that the error is thrown from within GetType(), the Nullable<T> situation will just throw the NullReferenceException in Program.Main.

Comment: @RussellGiddings This is not correct. The stack trace behaves as described above. Calling `GetType()` on a `null` reference type would produce a different trace but calling it on a `null` value type results in what is described above. See: https://dotnetfiddle.net/3zDtxc