# Would simple class instantiation ever fail in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, instantiation, out-of-memory

I saw some code written by another developer that looks something like this:

```
var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

if(stringBuilder == null)
{
    // Log memory allocation error
    // ...
    return;
}
```

(It is ALL over the place in the code )

Question 1:
Would that error logging code even get called?  If there was no memory, wouldn't an `System.OutOfMemoryException` be thrown on that first line?

Question 2:
Can a call to a constructor ever return null?

Comment: Technically it's possible for proxy classes and nullables, as Marc Gravell has pointed out, but it's such a pathological case that it's not worth considering: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194484/whats-the-strangest-corner-case-youve-seen-in-c-or-net

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're correct, and that code is wrong.  It will throw `OutOfMemoryException` on a failure.  This is clear in [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51y09td4%28VS.71%29.aspx):

> "If the new operator fails to allocate
>   memory, it throws the exception
>   OutOfMemoryException."

Constructors don't return anything, let alone null.  They manipulate an object that's already been allocated.

Answer (score 2):

My assumption is that the coder used to work in C++, and doesn't know how things work in C#.

Comment: The code is equally wrong for C++.  C++ `new` throws `bad_alloc` when allocation fails, unless you explicitly tell it not to.

Comment: That is exactly what one of the interns said here.  I myself haven't touched much C++, and not in a LONG time. Thanks.

Comment: @Matthew: yes -- if you are using Standard C++ (and know what you are doing).  Pre-Standard C++ returned null, and clearly the author isn't keeping his skills current.

Answer (score 2):

Now, this code is a different story:

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = null;

try { stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(); } catch(Exception) {}

if(stringBuilder == null)
{
    // Log memory allocation error
    // ...
    return;
}
```

In that case, string builder could (conceivably) be null.

Comment: Actually, the StringBuilder wouldn't be `null`, it would be uninitialized.

Comment: Actually, it will not even compile. But I think we can all assume Brian meant to write `StringBuilder stringBuilder = null;` instead :)

Comment: Sorry guys.  Fixed the code in the example.  Who needs a compiler?  I should just write a service that sends my code off to SO to be evaluated :)

Answer (score 1):

1. No. An OutOfMemoryException will be thrown if there isn't enough memory available to allocate an object.
2. No

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better version of the code. You would have much bigger problems if there is not enough memory to allocate a reference though.

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = null;

try {
   stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
}
catch(OutOfMemoryException) {
   // log memory error
}
```