# Ternary operator VB vs C#: why resolves Nothing to zero?

Tags: c#, vb.net, nullable, ternary-operator

I just shoot myself in the foot and would like to know whether there were actual reasons to make this situation possible.
And anyway, this question can stay for the convenience of the future foot shooters.

---

Suppose we have a nullable value in vb.net:

```vb
Dim i as Integer?
```

We want to assign a value to it, basing on a condition, and using a ternary operator, because it's so neat and stuff:

```vb
i = If(condition(), Nothing, 42)
```

That is, if a condition is `true`, employ the nullability, otherwise the value.
At which point the shooting occurs. For no apparent reason VB compiler decides that the common base type for `Nothing` and `Integer` is `Integer`, at which point it silently translates the statement to:

```vb
i = If(condition(), 0, 42)
```

---

Now, if you were to do this in C#:

```cs
i = (condition()) ? null : 42;
```

You would immediately get a compiler error saying that `<null>` doesn't mix well with `int`. Which is great, as my foot would have been healthier had I went the C# way this time. And for this to compile, you have to explicitly write:

```cs
i = (condition()) ? null : (int?)42;
```

---

Now, you *can* do the same in VB and get the correct null-ness you would expect:

```vb
i = If(condition(), Nothing, CType(42, Integer?))
```

But that requires having your foot shot in the first place. There's no compiler error and there's no warning. That's with `Explicit On` and `Strict On`.

---

So my question is, why?
Should I take this as a compiler bug?
Or can someone explain why the compiler behaves this way?

Comment: Because, as you are finding out, VB is a horrid language that does random stuff you didn't ask it to in a misguided effort to be helpful.

Comment: You would have to cast Nothing to Integer?.

Comment: @cdhowie - Don't knock it unless you've tried for more than a couple weeks. VB.Net has come a long way from vb6.

Comment: @Joel: I will agree with that, but a polished turd is still a turd.  :)

Comment: Yes, and the differences between VB and C# have become few and rare over the years.  This one isn't really a difference... the 'difference' is that `Nothing` and `null` have different meanings... it's easy to think you're doing the same thing, but you're not.

Comment: @cdhowie Anyone who hasn't learnt the special features of a new language will find that language frustrating. Anyone who blames the *language* for that frustration needs to reconsider their reaction.

Comment: @cdhowie You're obviously one of the people suffering from the **my language is better than yours syndrome**. Better get over it. VB is worth its salt. How many times [if ever] have you seen C# used as a macro/scripting language? And that's just for starters. I use both languages equally well and I don't complain.

Comment: @Alex Nah, I'm one of those people who has used a *lot* of different languages.  I started programming with C64 BASIC and from there moved to VB1 and eventually VB4, 5, 6, and .NET.  It's not like I haven't been around the VB block, and that makes it my language as much as anyone else's.  I've put up with its crap long enough to know why I don't like it.

Comment: When working with nullable ints, I prefer to say `new Integer?` instead of nothing. It is more verbose, but it elminates confusion.

Comment: @JonathanAllen And it's not more verbose than the 'correct' `i = If(condition(), Nothing, CType(42, Integer?))`:i.e. `i = If(condition(), New Integer?, 42)`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This is because VB's `Nothing` is not a direct equivalent to C#'s `null`.

For example, in C# this code will not compile:

```
int i = null;
```

But this VB.Net code works just fine:

```
Dim i As Integer = Nothing
```

VB.Net's `Nothing` is actually a closer match for C#'s `default(T)` expression.

Comment: Yes, it was a typo.  Fixed it now.

Comment: Phew, for a few seconds there I thought I was going to have to fix **a lot** of code!

Comment: this explains why `int i = null;` doesn't work, but if `int? i = 0;` and `int? i = null` both work, why doesn't `int? i = condition()? null : 0;` ???

Comment: @Jon I can't answer that, but he's asking about vb code. A translation of the vb to c# would be more like `int? i = condition()?default(int):0;`

Comment: Right. I completely overlooked the fact that you can `default()` a value type by setting to `Nothing`. Thanks, got it now.

Comment: @JonB Actually, I can answer this now. The `condition()?null:0` expression has to stand on it's own; the target of the assignment doesn't matter. When the compiler goes to infer a type for the expression, the untyped `null` and `0` operands are not obviously compatible, because `int?` is still a value type and there's other "magic" going on to allow you assign `null` to it. It would be nice if the compiler were smart enough to choose `int?` in that situation, but it won't do that yet.

Answer (score 12):

The ternary operator can only return one type.

In C#, it tries to choose a type based on `null` and `42`.  Well, `null` doesn't have a type, so it decides that the return type of the ternary operator is that of `42`; a plain old `int`.  Then it complains because you can't return null as a plain old `int`.  When you coerce 42 as a `int?`, the ternary operator is going to return an `int?`, so `null`'s valid.

Now, I don't know about VB, but quoting from the MSDN,
`Assigning Nothing to a variable sets it to the default value for its declared type.`

Which, since VB determines that the ternary operator will return an `int` (using the same process C# did), `Nothing` is `0`.  Again, coercing the `42` to be an `int?` turns `Nothing` into the default value of `int?`, which is `null`, as you expected.

Answer (score 2):

`Nothing` and `null` are not the same thing... from the MSDN:

> Assigning Nothing to a variable sets it to the default value for its declared type.

Also

> If you supply a value type in Expression, IsNothing always returns False.

Keep in mind that int? is a nullable type, but it's still a value type, not a reference type.

Try setting it to `DbNull.Value` instead of `Nothing`...

Answer (score 2):

I am thinking this has something more to do with IF than with Nothing. Consider this code:

```
''#     This raises an exception
Dim x As Integer?
x = If(True, Nothing, Nothing)
MessageBox.Show(x.Value)

''#     As does 
Dim x As Integer?
x = Nothing
MessageBox.Show(x.Value)

''#     Changing one of the truthpart arguments of If is what seems to return the zero.
Dim x As Integer?
x = If(True, Nothing, 5)
MessageBox.Show(x.Value)
```

Why it is doing this I still don't know, probably a question for the VB team. I don't think it has to do with the Nothing keyword or Nullable.

Comment: This has everything to do with Nothing being a Keyword and not a value.  As the accepted answer points out, nothing really means Default(T).  So,  in your first example T evaluates to Integer? and in your second it evaluates to Integer.  Which matches your results.

Answer (score 1):

In a number of cases `Nothing` will get converted to the default value. To use `Nothing` the same way you would use `null` you need to cast it to the correct nullable type.

```vb
Dim str As String
Dim int As Nullable(Of Integer) ' or use As Integer?
Dim reader As SqlDataReader
Dim colA As Integer = reader.GetOrdinal("colA")
Dim colB As Integer = reader.GetOrdinal("colB")
str = If(reader.IsDBNull(colA), DirectCast(Nothing, String), reader.GetString(colA))
int = If(reader.IsDBNull(colB), DirectCast(Nothing, Nullable(Of Integer)), reader.GetInt32(colB))
```

Answer (score -1):

This happens because Integer is not a reference type.  'Nothing' is only supposed to work for reference types. For value types assigning Nothing is automatically converted to the default value, which is in the case of an Integer 0.

Answer (score -1):

This is actually now possible in VS2015 (at the very least) by using New Integer?

Ex.:

> If(testInt> 0, testInt, New Integer?), where testInt is of type Integer?

Comment: The fact that `testInt` is of type `Integer?` already makes the entire expression `Integer?`, without a need for `New Integer?`. This was possible long before VS2015, and it is not what the question was about.