# VB.NET - Nullable DateTime and Ternary Operator

Tags: vb.net, datetime, nullable, ternary-operator

I'm having problems with a Nullable DateTime in VB.NET (VS 2010).

Method 1

```
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(LastCalibrationDateTextBox.Text) Then
    gauge.LastCalibrationDate = Nothing
Else
    gauge.LastCalibrationDate = DateTime.Parse(LastCalibrationDateTextBox.Text)
End If
```

Method 2

```
gauge.LastCalibrationDate = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(LastCalibrationDateTextBox.Text), Nothing, DateTime.Parse(LastCalibrationDateTextBox.Text))
```

When given an empty string Method 1 assigns a Null (Nothing) value to gauge.LastCalibrationDate but Method 2 assigns it the DateTime.MinValue.

In other places in my code I have:

```
LastCalibrationDate = If(IsDBNull(dr("LastCalibrationDate")), Nothing, dr("LastCalibrationDate"))
```

This correctly assigns Null (Nothing) from a Ternary Operator to a Nullable DateTime.

What am I missing?  Thanks!

Comment: Please can you add gauge.LastCalibrationData definition that you use in your code ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I will admit that I'm not an expert on this, but apparently it stems from two things:

1. The `If` ternary operator can return only one type, in this case a date type, not a nullable date type
2. The VB.Net `Nothing` value is not actually `null` but is equivalent to the default value of the specified type, in this case a date, not a nullable date. Hence the date minimum value.

I derived most of the information for this answer from this SO post: [Ternary operator VB vs C#: why resolves to integer and not integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147277/ternary-operator-vb-vs-c-why-resolves-to-integer-and-not-integer)

Hope this helps and that someone like Joel Coehoorn can shed more light on the subject.

Answer (score 18):

Bob Mc is correct. Pay extra attention to his second point - this isn't the case in C#.

What you need to do is force `Nothing` to a nullable DateTime by casting it as follows:

```
gauge.LastCalibrationDate = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(LastCalibrationDateTextBox.Text), CType(Nothing, DateTime?), DateTime.Parse(LastCalibrationDateTextBox.Text))
```

Here is a snippet to demonstrate:

```
Dim myDate As DateTime?
' try with the empty string, then try with DateTime.Now.ToString '
Dim input = ""
myDate = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(input), CType(Nothing, DateTime?), DateTime.Parse(input))
Console.WriteLine(myDate)
```

Instead of casting you can also declare a new nullable: `New Nullable(Of DateTime)` or `New DateTime?()`. The latter format looks a little odd but it's valid.

Comment: +1 Nice job adding the workaround that will produce the desired result.