# Problem Converting Byte() to Date()

Tags: .net, vb.net, ado.net, dbnull

I have a query in my DAL that results 1 item, a date. It's either a date or null. But I get an error when the value is null.

> Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Date' is not valid.

Query

```
Public Function GetOrderDepositByOrderID(ByVal OrderID As Integer) As Date
    myconn.Open()

    Dim date As Date

    Dim sql As String = "SELECT ifnull(OrderDeposit, '1900-01-01') FROM Order WHERE OrderID = ?"
    Dim cmd As New OdbcCommand(sql, myconn)

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("OrderID", OrderID)

    date= cmd.ExecuteScalar()

    'connectie sluiten
    myconn.Close()

    Return date
End Function
```

This is how I call my function.

```
If bllCust.getOrderDepositByOrderID(OrderID) = DBNull Then
   lblBoodschap.Text = ("Deposit not paid.\n")
Else
   lblBoodschap.Text = ("Deposit paid.\n")
End If
```

If the deposit is paid there's a date in the table, if not it's left null.

All help is welcome!

Comment: You can't convert DBNull to DateTime

Comment: If NULL is a valid value for your date then you should be using a Nullable<DateTime> to represent it.

Comment: How would I do that though? I've edited my post with the query too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited the database fields so that null values get a default value 1900-01-01, a date that will never be used.

Answer (score 3):

- Try to use [Convert.IsDBNull()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.isdbnull.aspx)
- Consider to return `Nullable<DateTime>` from `getOrderDepositByOrderID()` to check against null, not DBNull

---

in C# your code should like this:

```
return date = cmd.ExecuteScalar() as DateTime?;
```

I don't know [`operator as`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) analog in VB.NET

or

```
If Convert.IsDBNull(bllCust.getOrderDepositByOrderID(OrderID)) Then
    ...
Else
    ...
Else If
```

Comment: Where would I put that? Inside my query? I'll update my post with the query.

Comment: Where would I put that convert.isDBNULL?

Comment: but the field inside my table is already of the type 'date', wouldn't that still give me the same problem for fields with null?

Comment: @Tom: SQL type Date is related to .NET type System.DateTime. `Nullable<DateTime>` (or `DateTime?` in C#) is a DateTime that can be null. Most suitable solution to read from database

Comment: so DateTime is better than Date?

Comment: @Tom: The use `System.DataTime`. What type Date do you use now?

Comment: I just use Date as a type at the moment.

Comment: @Tom: What is fully qualified name of this type?

Comment: `Date` is the name of the type. Look in my original post to see the full version of how I use it.

Comment: @Tom: Ok, I see. Date is VB.NET alias for DateTime

Comment: @Tom: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189876/vb-net-nullable-datetime-and-ternary-operator, and [others](http://www.google.com/search?q=vb.net+nullable+dattime)

Comment: @Tom: So use `Nullable(Of DateTime)`

Comment: thanks for your help, but I still don't understand what I need to do.

Comment: Yes, I found that editing my select statement to `SELECT IFNULL(OrderDeposit, '1900-01-01') FROM Order WHERE OrderID = ?` works too, but now it says can't convert type Byte() to Date() :s

Answer (score 0):

Use the operand `IS` instead of `=`

```
If bllCust.getOrderDepositByOrderID(OrderID) Is DBNull Then
   lblBoodschap.Text = ("Deposit not paid.\n")
Else
   lblBoodschap.Text = ("Deposit paid.\n")
End If
```