# Assigning result of If operator to System.Nullable type

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

When using the **If** operator ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985(v=VS.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)) to assign a value to a **System.Nullable** object, if the result is Nothing (null), then 0 is assigned to the object.

Example:

```
'Expected value is null (Nothing). Actual value assigned is 0.
Dim x As System.Nullable(Of Integer) = If(1 = 0, 1, Nothing)
```

If x is a nullable type, why is it being assigned the default integer type of 0.  Shouldn't it receive a value of null?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Nothing` in the context of a value type resolves to the default value for that type. For an integer, this is just `0`.

The `If` operator does not do any conversions between its argument types, they are all treated equally – as `Integer` in your case. Hence your code is the same as

```
Dim x As Integer? = If(1 = 0, 1, 0)
```

To make the result nullable, you need to make the types explicit.

```
Dim x As Integer? = If(1 = 0, 1, CType(Nothing, Integer?))
```

Comment: Well, that works, but I still don't understand why.  A nullable type is not a value type.  If I set x = Nothing, then x is indeed null.  In addition, according to the MSDN documentation I linked in the original question, the If() operator evaluates the second two arguments as type Object.  Therefore, I would think that returning Nothing as type Object from the If() operator and assigning it to a nullable type would be the same as setting x = Nothing.  Why does it cast Nothing as type integer by default, forcing me to do an explicit CType()?

Comment: @NYSystemsAnalyst You misread the documentation. The argument types of `If` are *not* evaluated as `Object` (granted, the documentation is very misleading). Additionally, the return type (i.e. the type of the variable that we assign to) is never considered when resolving the type of the arguments to `If`, the only thing that’s considered are the argument types themselves. The compiler has just one requirement: have the same type for both operands, or be able to convert one implicitly to the other.

Comment: @NYSystemsAnalyst A nullable type is in fact a value type (you can look up System.Nullable in MSDN), just one that the language and IDE provide special handling for.

Comment: Thank you both.  I do believe the documentation for that operator is incomplete and misleading, but between your explanations and the explanations I found in these two similar questions, I believe I understand it much better.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147277/ternary-operator-vb-vs-c-why-resolves-to-integer-and-not-integer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189876/vb-net-nullable-datetime-and-ternary-operator

Answer (score 3):

Rather than return Nothing cast as Integer? Just create a new Integer? and return it.

Also, keep in mind when working with Nullable types, you should always use the .Value, .HasValue and .GetValueOrDefault methods on Nullable(Of T) rather than just returning the object. Thus in your case, the Value of X is indeed 0, but if you check the HasValue property it should return False to indicate the null situation. Similarly, if you want to check `If x = Nothing`, it will return False, but `If x.HasValue = False` returns True.

You could also write your example as follows which works correctly:

```
Dim x as Integer? = If(1=0, 1, new Integer?)
Console.WriteLine(x)
Console.WriteLine(x.HasValue)
```

Outputs:
null 
False