# How to set Date variable to null in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, date, null

I want to assign the `DOB` variable as null.

```
Dim DOB As Date = DTPSdob.Value
Dim datestring As String = DOB.ToString("d")
If chkSdob.Checked = False Then
      DOB = 'I want to assign here DOB variable as null'
Else
      DOB = datestring
End If
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use nullable datetime

```
    Dim DOB As Nullable(Of Date) = Date.Now
    Dim datestring As String = DOB.Value.ToString("d")
    DOB = Nothing
```

Comment: it should be DOB.Value.ToStrin("d"), updated answer, check now please

Answer (score 3):

“DateTime is a value type (a structure) and can not be set to null or nothing as with all .Net value types. The default value for a datetime value is zeros for the date portion and 12:00:00 AM for the Time portion.”

[VB.NET - Nullable DateTime and Ternary Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189876/vb-net-nullable-datetime-and-ternary-operator)

Comment: You have already given an answer. Don't try to correct other answers by editing them. Why do you want to have two answers that are exactly the same? Please use the comment system to point out mistakes. Thank you.

Comment: network problem. Same answer got posted twice, someone removed the second, thanks whoever it is

Comment: That's not what I meant. You seem to have [**tried to edit alliswell's answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1136365) so it looks just like yours.

Comment: I thought the question was on Date and not DateTime?

Comment: @ AltF4_ harness the power thereof, not the syntax

Comment: @phant0m I did not try to edit anyone's answer. Could you please focus on the assistance that I am trying to provide, not a mere network error. Please...

Answer (score -2):

Change the DOB from a date variable to an object variable.  You can then pass nothing or a valid date into the variable.  That variable can then be used update the database.

```
dim DOB as object = nothing
If chkSdob.Checked = True Then
  DOB = datestring
end if
```

Comment: Why bother? when you have no idea what the question is