# SQL String providing time instead of Null

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, sql-update

I have a SQL statement that pulls information based on a key value. If the record count is > 0 meaning there is a record there, it pulls a date along with other information.

For the particular person I'm referencing - it skips this line of code (because there is no records) but still displays 12:00:00 AM for the date while the other fields are blank.

Below is the information for the SQL. I created an object and pulled all the information into it which I'm passing into the call in Access VBA.

What am I doing wrong?

```
strSQL = "SELECT ASSOCIATE.PERSONNEL_NUM, PART.PART_SSNO, PART.TAG, PART.DATE, PART.NOTES FROM PART INNER JOIN HASSOCIATE ON PART.PART_SSNO = ASSOCIATE.SSNO WHERE PART.PART_SSNO = " & strVar

Set rst= CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

 If rst.RecordCount > 0 Then
    objPartInfo.Tag= IIf(Len(Nz(rst!TAG, "")) > 0, Trim(rst!TAG), "0")
    objPartInfo.Date= IIf(Len(Nz(rst!DATE, "")) > 0, (rst!DATE), #12/31/9999#)
    objPartInfo.Notes = Trim(Nz(rst!NOTES, ""))

Else
    'do something
End If
```

The update query below, updates an additional table with the information pulled from the SQL string above.

```
strSQL = "UPDATE [TBLparticipants] " SET [TBLparticipants].[PartFrozenDate] = #" & objPartInfo.FrozenDate & "#, [TBLparticipants].[PartFrozen] = '" & objPartInfo.Frozen & "', [TBLparticipants].[PartFrozenNotes] = '" & apostrophe(objPartInfo.Notes) & "', WHERE [TBLparticipants].[PartSS#]= " & CLng(objPartInfo.SSNO)
```

Comment: I dont know what you are talking about but if it hits the else just assign the date field to empty / null.

Comment: @JonH when I set them to null I get a type mismatch error on the date call.

Comment: You will need to show how you set it to null.  YOu need a nullable datetime https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189876/vb-net-nullable-datetime-and-ternary-operator

Comment: @JonH I was able to force the null on the Update call. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of opening a recordset just to get a record count or pull a single value, could use DCount() or DLookup().