# VB.NET: How do I use coalesce with db column values and nullable types? Or is there a better solution?

Tags: vb.net, nullable, dbnull

I'm trying to do something similar to what's described here, but with nullable types.

http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/Lesson23.aspx

```
int availableUnits = unitsInStock ?? 0;
```

In VB, it would be this:

```
Dim availableUnits As Int32 = If(unitsInStock, 0)
```

However I'm working with db columns, which could be DbNull, and nullable types, which can be Nothing (which is different to DbNull). If a column is DbNull, I want to return Nothing, otherwise return the value. For eg:

```
Dim availableUnits As Int32? = If(myDataReader("UnitsInStock").Value, Nothing)
```

The error I'm getting is "Specified cast is not valid" but I'm not sure why. I've tried this as well:

```
Dim availableUnits As Int32? = If(isDbNull(myDataReader("UnitsInStock").Value), myDataReader("UnitsInStock").Value, Nothing)
```

Which is messy and just results in the same error. The only thing that works is this:

```
Dim availableUnits As Int32?
If isDbNull(myDataReader("UnitsInStock").Value) Then
  availableUnits = myDataReader("UnitsInStock").Value
Else
  availableUnits = Nothing
End If
```

Which is just silly. Is there a better way of getting nullable db values into nullable variables that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is silly, but you have to cast the `Nothing` when you set it:

```
Dim availableUnits As Int32? = If(myDataReader.IsDBNull("UnitsInStock"), _
                                  CType(Nothing, Int32?), _
                                  myDataReader.GetInt32("UnitsInStock"))
```

Comment: Very true, and very weird, just discovered this after an hour of head scratching. Looks like this is about as simple as it gets. Many thanks.

Comment: This problem arises because `Nothing` in VB does not necessarily mean `null`. See this question for details: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4147277/87698

Comment: @Heinzi - I believe the same is true of C#, requiring the cast, i.e., `(Int32?)null`.

Answer (score 3):

If using DataSets instead of DataReaders is an option for you, the [DataRow.Field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method knows how to handle Nullable variables properly:

```
Dim availableUnits = myDataRow.Field(Of Int32?)("UnitsInStock")
```

Comment: Thanks, that's definitely handy to know. In this case though, need to work with the datareader.

Answer (score 1):

As I mention in what turns out to be [a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14663808/256431) you are best served by not using `Nothing` here, but rather `New Int32?`:

```
Dim availableUnits = If(myDataReader.IsDBNull("UnitsInStock"), _
                              New Int32?, _
                              myDataReader.GetInt32("UnitsInStock"))
```