# VB Net IsDBNull issue

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have an Issue with the IsDBNull method.
This is my code:

```
   Dim a as Bool=  IIf(IsDBNull(reader("field")), _
                       False, _
                       Convert.ToBoolean(reader("field")))
```

The code above should return *False* if the column is false but I get the exception:

> Impossible to cast DBNull to other types.

The Convert.ToBoolean fails

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB.NET: How do I use coalesce with db column values and nullable types? Or is there a better solution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8436677/vb-net-how-do-i-use-coalesce-with-db-column-values-and-nullable-types-or-is-th)

Comment: Disagree on that Q as a duplicate: that question is about casting `nothing` (`null`) to the right kind of null; this is about order of evaluation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All arguments of `Iif` are evaluated when called, whether they'll be used or not.

In this respect it is *not equivalent* to C#'s conditional operator (which only evaluates the boolean control sub-expression and one of the other two sub-exptressions).

You need to use VB.Net's [`If`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx) operator which does do lazy evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

```
If(IsDBNull(reader("field"))) then 
return False

else 

Convert.ToBoolean(reader("field")))

end if
```

IIF will evaluate failed part also.