# Is there a VB.NET expression that *always* yields null?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

We all know that VB's `Nothing` is similar, but not equivalent, to C#'s `null`. (If you are not aware of that, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4147321/87698) first.)

Just out of curiosity, I'd like to know the following:

**Is there a VB.NET expression that always yields `null`?**

---

To give a concrete example, take the following statement:

```
Dim o As Object = If(myBool, 5, ...)
```

Is it possible to replace `...` with something, such that `o` is `5` when `myBool` is true and `Nothing/null` when `myBool` is false?

Obvious solutions that won't work:

- `Nothing` (see the question to the linked answer above),
- `DirectCast(Nothing, Object)` (throws a compile-time error with Option Strict On),
- `DirectCast(Nothing, Integer?)` works for this example, but does not work *in general* (if you replace `5` with `5.0` in this example, you'd need to modify the cast).

Obvious workarounds (won't count as answers):

- Declare an `Object` variable or field, set it to `Nothing` and use that for `...`,
- define a method or property that always returns `Nothing`,
- `DirectCast` the second parameter (`5`) to `Object`.

*Note: The example above is just an example. The question itself is written in bold.*

Comment: Do you want a one-liner that works for both reference and value types? What if the value type is not nullable? Can you show the _usage_ of this code?

Comment: Your question is not that clear, why do you need to get `null` always? What's wrong with using a nullable type instead of object? If your example is  interchangeable provide a better example where `Int32?` is not an option.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I imagine that something like that could be useful when writing an automated C#->VB.NET converter, but mainly I'm just curious. I don't see how the question is unclear: "VB.NET expression" is well-defined, and the desired return value of the expression is clearly stated in the question.

Comment: If the answer you linked is the only difference between Nothing and null, this question doesn't make sense. default(T) will yield null for any type where it's possible to yield null. So what you're asking would essentially be: "Is there a VB.NET expression that yields null not only for types where it is possible, but ones where it isn't?"

Comment: @TimSchmelter: "No, there is definitely no such expression" would be a perfectly fine answer.

Comment: So... you want an answer to your question, but you don't want any of the "*obvious*" answers?  How is this a real question?

Comment: With Option Strict Off, it still won't be quite the same even if you have a true null: `0 = DirectCast(Nothing, Object)` returns true. (In C#, `0 == null` is false.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first answer I gave missed some points, but this should do it:

```
Dim o As Object = If(myBool, 5, DirectCast(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(GetType(Integer)), Object))
```

This uses the fact that [`Nullable.GetUnderlyingType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullable.getunderlyingtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will return a null reference if you pass it a type which isn't a nullable value type - which `Integer` isn't. Other alternatives exist, such as `Type.GetElementType()`, or perhaps `GetType(Object).BaseType`.

I've checked that this works with multiple different types for the second operand.

It's slightly annoying that you have to cast to `Object`... I'm still working on alternatives for that...

Comment: @Heinzi: Ah - the purpose of that point wasn't obvious to me. Can you put this into a generic method instead? (That would certainly be simpler than all this messing around.)

Comment: @Heinzi: And actually, this code *still* works if you change it to 5.0.

Comment: @Heinzi: Ah - I didn't have Option Strict On. Ignore my previous comment :(

Comment: @JonSkeet: As I said, I'm just curious if such an expression exists. I know that there are multiple ways to work around the issue.

Comment: @Heinzi: Yes, I've found one. Editing now :)

Answer (score 7):

The simple answer is, no.  There is no expression in VB.NET that only returns `null`.  As you know, when the compiler parses a command using ternary operator, it infers the output type based on the two inputs.  If one of the two inputs is `Nothing`, it must rely solely on the other parameter.  Therefore, the "right" way to do it in VB.NET is to first cast the other parameter to `Object`, thereby forcing the output of the operation to be an `Object`:

```
Dim o As Object = If(myBool, DirectCast(5, Object), Nothing)
```

If, however, you really need an in-line expression which, itself, always evaluates to `null`, you could always do it by invoking a lambda expression, like this:

```
Dim o As Object = If(myBool, 5.0, (Function() Nothing).Invoke())
```

That syntax should work in any situation and would always result in `Nothing` rather than potentially resulting in default value.

Comment: True. However, please see Point 3 of "Obvious workarounds (won't count as answers)".

Comment: Oops.  Read the question to fast I guess :(

Comment: I updated my answer to include another, albeit ugly, solution which *kind of* meets your criteria.

Answer (score 0):

`System.DBNull.Value` is most likely what you're after.

**Expansion, from Tech Republic:**

> ... The following C# code determines if a string value is null:

```
string sTest = "Test"; if (sTest == null) { Console.WriteLine("sTest is Null"); }
```

> This code works without any problems with C#, but there's no VB.NET equivalent of the null keyword. Instead, VB.NET uses the Nothing keyword. The following code demonstrates its use:

```
Dim sTest As String
If (sTest Is Nothing) Then
    Console.WriteLine("sTest is Null") 
End If
```

> Another area of confusion stems from the fact that VB.NET doesn't treat null and Nothing as equals; consequently, a VB.NET programmer may have to check for both values.
>
> The variation in support may cause confusion, but a developer rarely develops in both languages simultaneously. On the other hand, Microsoft provides a uniform method for working with null values: The base `System.Convert` namespace includes the `DBNull` object.
>
> **`DBNull`**
>
> The use of the `DBNull` class indicates the absence of a known value.
>   While the Microsoft documentation says it's typically in a database
>   application, you may also use it with any type of data.

```
If (sTest.Equals(System.DBNull.Value) Then
    Console.WriteLine("sTest is Null")
End  If
```

-- verbatim from [Working with Null values in the .NET Framework](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/working-with-null-values-in-the-net-framework/)

Comment: `System.DBNull.Value IsNot Nothing`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create one yourself (pick a different name for the function if you like):

```
Private Function ValueOrNull(expression As Boolean, value As Object) As Object
  If expression Then Return value
  Return Nothing
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Dim myBool As Boolean
Dim o As Object = ValueOrNull(myBool, 5)
```

Works with any type, including your example with `5.0`.