# What's going on with my assignment of Nothing to an Int32?

Tags: vb.net

I have a couple class properties defined like:

```
Property CustomerKey As Int32
Property ProductStructureHeaderKey As Int32?
```

At one point in my code, immediately after declaring an instance of that class, I try to set those two values with:

```
    dps.CustomerKey = row.Cells(2).Value
    dps.ProductStructureHeaderKey = If(row.Cells(1).Value Is Nothing, Nothing, Int32.Parse(row.Cells(1).Value))
```

My problem is that when the value in row.Cells(1) is Nothing, the ProductStructureHeaderKey ends up equal to 0, not Nothing. And it seems like it should work because this works:

```
    dps.ProductStructureHeaderKey = Nothing
```

So that makes me think that I'm actually doing If() wrong, but I use that all the time and can't imagine what's going on.

So...thoughts?

---

Related to the above, why do I seem to need to Int32.Parse() the value when assigning it to a nullable Int32, but not in the first case?

Comment: If there is no data for `row.Cells(1).Value` it will be `DBNull` not `Nothing`

Comment: @Plutonix Debugger shows it as Nothing.

Comment: This reminds me of a [similar question that you may find interesting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22147728/is-there-a-vb-net-expression-that-always-yields-null).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Nothing' in VB means 'default value' of the type in question. In your 'If' statement, VB knows that 'Int32.Parse(row.Cells(1).Value)' is an integer, not a nullable Integer, so it interprets 'Nothing' in the 'If' statements as an integer.  'Nothing' applied to 'Integer' is 0.

You can use:

```
If(row.Cells(1).Value Is Nothing, CType(Nothing, Integer?), Int32.Parse(row.Cells(1).Value))
```

A common source of confusion with these sorts of issues is that 'Nothing' in VB is not the same as 'null' in C# - 'Nothing' in VB always has the meaning of "default value" of the type in question.

Comment: I thought one of the primary differences between If() and IIf() was that the terms weren't evaluated. But it sounds like you're saying the Int32.Parse() is being looked at least enough for type inference even though it knows from the left side of the assignment that the type should be Nullable(Of Int32). Is that right?

Comment: Yes and no - only the required term is evaluated at runtime (this is the difference between the 'IIf' function and the 'If' operator) - at compile time VB will determine what the common type of both the 'true' and 'false' terms are.

Comment: Note that first VB determines the right side of the assignment - this is found to be 'Integer'.  An assignment of Integer to Integer? (the left side) is valid, so that's the end of it.

Comment: Great, thanks! That code works and it's satisfying to know what's going on under the hood.