# Nullable type inference in Visual Basic – is it documented somewhere and can it be made more strict?

Tags: .net, vb.net, nullable, type-inference

Guess the result of `i`:

```vb
Dim i As Integer? = If(True, Nothing, 3)
```

Answer: `0`

If you expect to get `Nothing`, you have to modify the integer argument:

```vb
Dim i As Integer? = If(True, Nothing, New Nullable(3))
```

As you can see, inference of result type from 2nd and 3rd parameter prefers `T` before `Nullable(Of T)`. For me, logical would be the contrary.

**Where these inference/prioritization rules of types (especially of `Nullable`) can be found documented?** I checked help for `type inference`, `Nullable` and `If`, but I can't find anything.

A peek to the neighbors: [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) (nicely) refuses to compile the equivalent

```c#
int? i = true ? null : 3;
```

with error

> CS0173    Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between `'<null>'` and 'int'

what is safe and avoids fall into the catch seen in the [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net). But in the VB, even `Option Infer Off`+`Option Strict On` do not have any error-throwing effect, which could save programmer from unnoticed errors. **Or is there a way to generate an error also in the [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net)?**

Comment: @GSerg – hah, I was always wondering whether a valid reason can exist that I'll vote for closing my own question. Now I voted...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, now I understand better. The culprit is in interpretation of `Nothing`.

Change of `Nothing` to “true” `null` leads to correct result:

```vb
Dim i As Integer? = If(True, New Nullable(Of Integer), 3)
```

Result: `i Is Nothing`

so the possible problem was that `Nothing` seems to be first viewed by compiler as default value for the other type (Integer) than a `null`. Changing its implicit meaning helps. A tricky spot anyway. **If someone can find this documented, it would be nice.** (I do not insist on this answer.) It will be great if the VB can be forced to throw an error or warning when this happens, similar to C#.

---

As seen in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147277/ternary-operator-vb-vs-c-why-resolves-nothing-to-zero#comment4529159_4147277) elsewhere, a nicer form of notation can exist:

```vb
Dim i As Integer? = If(True, Integer?, 3)
```

Nice!

Comment: This also would have worked - Dim i As Integer? = If(True, Nothing, New Nullable(Of Integer)(3))