# VB.NET 2015 Nullable Integer Not Working with If() operator?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, nullable

Why is this result **0** (zero) and NOT **Nothing**?

```
Dim foobar As Integer? = If(False, 1, Nothing)
```

[From Microsoft Documentation:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/visual-basic/language-reference/nothing)

> If a variable is of a value type, the behavior of Nothing depends on
>   whether the variable is of a nullable data type. To represent a
>   nullable value type, add a ? modifier to the type name. Assigning
>   Nothing to a nullable variable sets the value to null. For more
>   information and examples, see Nullable Value Types.

Further research yields even more *interesting* results:

```
Dim foo As Integer? = If(False, 1, Nothing)             '0
Dim bar As String = If(False, 1, Nothing)               '"0"
Dim bar2 As String = If(False, "1", Nothing)            'Nothing
Dim bar3 As Integer? = If(False, "1", Nothing)          'Nothing
Dim bar4 As Integer? = If(False, CStr(1), Nothing)      '0
```

Does the following suggest that the result type is predicated on the ***type*** second value?

```
Dim bar3 As Integer? = If(False, "1", Nothing)          'Nothing
```

---

**EDITED** with additional finding  and desired result, but why should BOTH arguments need to be evaluated and not just the short-circuited version of If()?

```
Dim foo As Integer? = IIf(False, 1, Nothing)             'Nothing
```

Comment: `If` produces a result of a specific type. That type is inferred from the two possible return values (1 and `Nothing` in your first example), not from the type of the variable that the result is being assigned to. As `Nothing` can be assigned to an Integer (giving it the value 0), the compiler assumes that the return type is Integer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ternary operator VB vs C#: why resolves Nothing to zero?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147277/ternary-operator-vb-vs-c-why-resolves-nothing-to-zero)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Blackwood -- I added another twist in an edit at the same time your answer came in.

Comment: The type of the result is evaluated at compile time. The compiler doesn't (usually) know which of the two results will be picked at run time, so it can't base the type of the result on that.

Comment: It was a late addition to the language.  The VB.NET team held off demands for a fix to the IIf() function (like any method call, all arguments get evaluated) but had to do something when Linq was added. It is the least-worst choice they made, expressions are also valid in statements that are not assignments and type inference is crucial in Linq.

Comment: @HumbleBeginnings I believe closing as duplicate is also a (kind?) offering of explanation. Closing as duplicate is another way of solving people's problems (by pointing them to existing answers), not a way of punishing them for asking what's been asked before. I am pretty sure that 6 years old answer fully answers your question, and if your question is ultimately closed as duplicate, it will serve other people with the same problem as a search point (they will enter keywords similar to those of your choice, will find your question, and will follow to the answer).

Comment: Thanks, @HansPassant . My question is getting pretty beat up here, I am glad that a least I mentioned "something" of value. :)

Answer (score 4):

A fix for If operator,

```
Dim foo As Integer? = If(False, 1, New Nullable(Of Integer))
```

and one other

```
    Dim foo As Integer?
    If True Then
        foo = 1
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to dbasnett's answer, you can do:

```
Dim foo As Integer? = If(False, 1, CType(Nothing, Integer?))
```