# if operator does not return empty decimal

Tags: vb.net

Why using the following syntax the *if operator* does not return an empty decimal as expected ?

```
    Dim d As Decimal?
    d = If(false, 10, Nothing)

    Console.WriteLine("d.HasValue: " + d.HasValue().ToString())
```

Working workaround follows:

```
    Dim d As Decimal?
    Dim NullDecimal As Decimal?
    d = If(false, 10, NullDecimal)
```

Comment: Use `New Decimal?` instead of `Nothing`. I.E., `d = If(false, 10, New Decimal?)`.

Comment: Another duplicate: [Ternary operator VB vs C#: why resolves Nothing to zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4147277/4934172)